# Java: Writing a DOM to an XML file (formatting issues)

Tags: java, xml, formatting, pretty-print

I'm using `org.w3c` `XML API` to open an existing `XML` file. I'm removing some nodes , and I'm adding others instead.

The problem is that the new nodes that are added are written one after the other, with no newline and no indentation what so ever. While it's true that the `XML` file is valid , it is very hard for a human to examine it.

Is there anyway to add indentation , or at least a newline after each node?

Comment: If you've come to this question looking for code examples for how to pretty print XML in Java then see [how to pretty print xml from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java) instead.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using a [`Transformer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) to do the actual writing (to a [`StreamResult`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html)). In which case, do this before you call `transform`:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
```

Comment: BTW: in latest jdk there is a bug to get around this you will need to do before: TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();             tFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 2);

Comment: Cheers @Karussell that managed to fix the issues I was having

Answer (score 17):

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
```

source
[How to pretty print XML from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few good examples of "pretty printing" in the following thread

[how to pretty print xml from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java)

[Link to my effort at a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java#260314)