# Creating XML only printing to one line

Tags: java, xml, dom

I created some code that writes a map to XML. It appears to be working but the file is printed with no new lines. So in any XML editor its only on one line. How can I have it print to a new line for each child?

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.newDocument();

Element vdata = doc.createElement("vouchdata");
doc.appendChild(vdata);

for (Entry<String, String> entry : vouchMap.entrySet()) {
    Element udata = doc.createElement("vouch");

    Attr vouchee = doc.createAttribute("name");
    vouchee.setValue(entry.getKey());
    udata.setAttributeNode(vouchee);

    Attr voucher = doc.createAttribute("vouchedBy");
    voucher.setValue(entry.getValue());
    udata.setAttributeNode(voucher);

    vdata.appendChild(udata);
}

// write the content into xml file
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("vouchdata.xml"));

// Output to console for testing
// StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264849/pretty-printing-output-from-javax-xml-transform-transformer-with-only-standard-j

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I use

```
Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
tf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
```

Which seems to work just fine.

Comment: @Tony This little hack to me weeks for Googling and trial and error.  Glad I saved you the hasel ;)

Comment: Perfect: it helped me so much after half a day trying to find out what is wrong with my XML output (long one line only) - this solved it, upvoted!

Answer (score -1):

If it is formatting of generated xml then consider the answer for

[Java: Writing a DOM to an XML file (formatting issues)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161462/java-writing-a-dom-to-an-xml-file-formatting-issues)