# Best pretty-printing library for Java?

Tags: java, io, pretty-print

What is the single best pretty-printing library for Java? I mean a library for printing formatted output with indentation, break hints, etc., *not* a library for beautifying/re-formatting Java code itself. Ideally, the library would "play nice" with `System.out.println` and friends.

For an idea of what I'm looking for, see OCaml's [Format module](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview/batteries-alpha2/doc/batteries/html/api/Languages.Format.html), particularly [Format.fprintf](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview/batteries-alpha2/doc/batteries/html/api/Languages.Format.html#VALfprintf).

[UPDATE] I am not looking for a console windowing library. A pretty-printing library allows you to define methods for formatting arbitrary values such that indentation is preserved and line breaks are chosen at sensible locations. Such libraries exist for [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/haskell-src/Language-Haskell-Pretty.html), [Standard ML](http://smlnj.org/doc/Compiler/pages/prettyprint.html), [OCaml](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview/batteries-alpha2/doc/batteries/html/api/Languages.Format.html), [F#](http://www.intellifactory.com/articles/PrettyPrinter.aspx), and [Scheme](http://www.cs.aau.dk/~normark/scheme/lib/man/scheme-pretty-printing.html). The [XTC library](http://cs.nyu.edu/rgrimm/xtc/) provides some of this functionality in `xtc.tree.Printer`, but it is not nearly as flexible as the libraries in other languages.

Answer (score 2):

Is it [jpplib](http://jpplib.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score -1):

Since you talk about boxes, break hints and so on I assume you mean to build a text-based windowing application. So I guess that you are looking for something similar to [Ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) but in Java. Maybe [charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/Screenshots.html) could help you.

Comment: No, I'm no developing a curses application. I just want nice, formatted output, e.g., in debugging logs. I can't find any appropriate classes in charva.

Answer (score -1):

You may also try [javacurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/).

According to [Dr. Dobb's Code Talk](http://dobbscodetalk.com/index.php?option=com_myblog&show=Curses-in-Java.html&Itemid=29) it is cute.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do what I want.

Answer (score -1):

I would say its still easier using Xalan + Sax, like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java).