# Pretty printing XML with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, pretty-print

I have a string that represents a non indented XML that I would like to pretty-print. For example:

```
<root><node/></root>
```

should become:

```
<root>
  <node/>
</root>
```

Syntax highlighting is not a requirement. To tackle the problem I first transform the XML to add carriage returns and white spaces and then use a [*pre*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4) tag to output the XML. To add new lines and white spaces I wrote the following function:

```
function formatXml(xml) {
    var formatted = '';
    var reg = /(>)(<)(\/*)/g;
    xml = xml.replace(reg, '$1\r\n$2$3');
    var pad = 0;
    jQuery.each(xml.split('\r\n'), function(index, node) {
        var indent = 0;
        if (node.match( /.+<\/\w[^>]*>$/ )) {
            indent = 0;
        } else if (node.match( /^<\/\w/ )) {
            if (pad != 0) {
                pad -= 1;
            }
        } else if (node.match( /^<\w[^>]*[^\/]>.*$/ )) {
            indent = 1;
        } else {
            indent = 0;
        }

        var padding = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < pad; i++) {
            padding += '  ';
        }

        formatted += padding + node + '\r\n';
        pad += indent;
    });

    return formatted;
}
```

I then call the function like this:

```
jQuery('pre.formatted-xml').text(formatXml('<root><node1/></root>'));
```

This works perfectly fine for me but while I was writing the previous function I thought that there must be a better way. So my question is do you know of any better way given an XML string to pretty-print it in an html page? Any javascript frameworks and/or plugins that could do the job are welcome. My only requirement is this to be done on the client side.

Comment: For a fancy HTML output (ala IE XML display), see the XSLT transformation used in the XPath Visualizer. You can download the XPath Visualizer at: http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html

Comment: /.+<\/\w[^>]*>$/ - remove "+" in this RegExp as it slows down the code in some JavaScript engines, for nodes with "long attribute values".

Answer (score 61, accepted):

From the text of the question **I get the impression that a string result is expected**, as opposed to an HTML-formatted result.

If this is so, **the simplest way to achieve this is to process the XML document with the [identity transformation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and with an [`<xsl:output indent="yes"/>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-XML-Output-Method) instruction**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applying this transformation on the provided XML document:

```
<root><node/></root>
```

most XSLT processors (.NET XslCompiledTransform, Saxon 6.5.4 and Saxon 9.0.0.2, AltovaXML) produce the wanted result:

```
<root>
  <node />
</root>
```

Comment: It looks like a great solution. Is there any cross browser way to apply this transformation in javascript? I don't have a server side script to rely on.

Comment: Yes. Look at Sarissa: http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/  and here: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/02/23/sarissa.html

Comment: This doesn't work on chrome.  I should have checked if Sarissa works on chrome first.  Wasted almost an hour on this.

Comment: @ablmf: What "doesn't work"? What is "Chrome"? I never heard of such XSLT processor. Also, if you have a look at the date of the answer, the Chrome browser was non-existent at that time.

Comment: @ablmf: Also note that this question (and my answer to it) is to get the prettyfied XML as a string (text) and not HTML. No wonder such a string doesn't display in a browser. For a fancy HTML output (ala IE XML display), see the XSLT transformation used in the XPath Visualizer. You can download the XPath Visualizer at: http://huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html . You may need to adjust the code a little bit (such as to remove the javascript extension functions for collapsing/expanding a node), but otherwise the resulting HTML should display fine.

Comment: @Darin Try PrettyDiff.com that application uses http://prettydiff.com/markup_beauty.js to beautify XML/HTML.

Comment: The original question asked for a method using javascript. How does one get this answer to work with javascript?

Comment: JohnK, In 2008, when this question was answered, people were initiating XSLT transformations from JavaScript in IE -- invoking MSXML3. Now they still can do this, though the XSLT processor that comes with IE11 is MSXML6. All other browsers have similar capabilities, though they have different built-in XSLT processors. This is why the original asker never raised such question.

Comment: Looks like Chrome and other browsers have XSLT support now: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp

Comment: @SarahVessels, The mentioned browsers did have XSLT support in 2010. It is good to remember, though, that all these only support XSLT 1.0

Comment: All modern browser support xslt 1.0: `new XSLTProcessor()`

Comment: Used this approach is Java app (no external libraries involved).

Comment: It works in Chrome 81 (but only with transformToDocument)

Comment: I agree with the other commenters' confusion. The question asks for a JavaScript function, and this answer contains an XSLT Transformation **and no JavaScript function** to apply it.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude, If one reads and understand the question, they will know that: 1. The question is tagged with "xslt"; 2. The OP describes how he tried first to do all with XSLT; 3. Only then he continued with Javascript, because he couldn't do all in XSLT; 4. This answer was accepted by the OP, which means that it best met his needs for an appropriate solution. So, to summarize, this answer was accepted exactly because it provides a pure XSLT solution.

Answer (score 79):

This can be done using [native](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor) javascript tools, without 3rd party libs, extending the @Dimitre Novatchev's answer:

```js
var prettifyXml = function(sourceXml)
{
    var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(sourceXml, 'application/xml');
    var xsltDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString([
        // describes how we want to modify the XML - indent everything
        '<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">',
        '  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>',
        '  <xsl:template match="para[content-style][not(text())]">', // change to just text() to strip space in text nodes
        '    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>',
        '  </xsl:template>',
        '  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">',
        '    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>',
        '  </xsl:template>',
        '  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>',
        '</xsl:stylesheet>',
    ].join('\n'), 'application/xml');

    var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();    
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);
    var resultDoc = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlDoc);
    var resultXml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDoc);
    return resultXml;
};

console.log(prettifyXml('<root><node/></root>'));
```

Outputs:

```
<root>
  <node/>
</root>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/klesun/sgeryvyu/369/)

Note, as pointed out by @jat255, pretty printing with [`<xsl:output indent="yes"/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/Element/output) is not supported by firefox. It only seems to work in chrome, opera and probably the rest webkit-based browsers.

Comment: Very nice answer, but unfortunately Internet Explorer.spoils the party again.

Comment: nice, it works only when input xml is a single line... if you do not care about multi lines  in text nodes, before calling prettify, call ```private makeSingleLine(txt: string): string {
let s = txt.trim().replace(new RegExp("\r", "g"), "\n");
let angles = ["<", ">"];
let empty = [" ", "\t", "\n"];
while (s.includes(" <") || s.includes("\t<") || s.includes("\n<") || 
s.includes("> ") || s.includes(">\t") || s.includes(">/n")) {
angles.forEach(an => {
empty.forEach(em => { s = s.replace(new RegExp(em + an, "g"), an); });
});
}
return s.replace(new RegExp("\n", "g"), " ");
}```

Comment: I get an error, but the error has no message. It happens in the fiddle too, using firefox.

Comment: This also is not working for me with a blank error in Firefox

Comment: This is discussed at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989864/undefined-undefined-error-when-calling-xsltprocessor-prototype-importstylesheet Apparently, Firefox needs a version specification for the xsl, but it doesn't matter anyway because the Mozilla implementation does not respect any `xsl:output` tag, so you won't get the nice formatting anyway.

Answer (score 46):

Found this thread when I had a similar requirement but I simplified OP's code as follows:

```
function formatXml(xml, tab) { // tab = optional indent value, default is tab (\t)
    var formatted = '', indent= '';
    tab = tab || '\t';
    xml.split(/>\s*</).forEach(function(node) {
        if (node.match( /^\/\w/ )) indent = indent.substring(tab.length); // decrease indent by one 'tab'
        formatted += indent + '<' + node + '>\r\n';
        if (node.match( /^<?\w[^>]*[^\/]$/ )) indent += tab;              // increase indent
    });
    return formatted.substring(1, formatted.length-3);
}
```

works for me!

Comment: I tried a few of the `xsltProcessor` answers and they all worked 100% in my browsers. But I found this answer good & simple as it was easy to unit-test -  XSLT is not  part of Node.js which is used during my Jest tests & I didn't want to install it just for UT. Also I read at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor   -  *This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.*

Comment: BTW ESLint tells me there is an unnecessary escape and my IDE autocorrects to `(/^<?\w[^>]*[^/]$/))`

Comment: `/^<?\w[^>]*[^\/]$/` fails when the tag is only one-letter long, *e.g.* `<a>`. Suggest using `/^<?\w([^>/]*|[^>]*[^/])$/` maybe.

Comment: suggested [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fbn5j7ya/) edit, which is almost 2x faster. functional loops and regex are [slow](https://jsbench.me/zhkm1virni/3)

Comment: @milahu: You answer is excellent.  Please post as a separate answer!  Also: You should add a small doc to your code: To get minified XML, pass: tab = "" and nl = "".

Comment: Warning, this solution will give you unexpected results on XML with [CDATA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CDATASection) blocks.

Answer (score 34):

Slight modification of efnx clckclcks's javascript function.  I changed the formatting from spaces to tab, but most importantly I allowed text to remain on one line:

```
var formatXml = this.formatXml = function (xml) {
        var reg = /(>)\s*(<)(\/*)/g; // updated Mar 30, 2015
        var wsexp = / *(.*) +\n/g;
        var contexp = /(<.+>)(.+\n)/g;
        xml = xml.replace(reg, '$1\n$2$3').replace(wsexp, '$1\n').replace(contexp, '$1\n$2');
        var pad = 0;
        var formatted = '';
        var lines = xml.split('\n');
        var indent = 0;
        var lastType = 'other';
        // 4 types of tags - single, closing, opening, other (text, doctype, comment) - 4*4 = 16 transitions 
        var transitions = {
            'single->single': 0,
            'single->closing': -1,
            'single->opening': 0,
            'single->other': 0,
            'closing->single': 0,
            'closing->closing': -1,
            'closing->opening': 0,
            'closing->other': 0,
            'opening->single': 1,
            'opening->closing': 0,
            'opening->opening': 1,
            'opening->other': 1,
            'other->single': 0,
            'other->closing': -1,
            'other->opening': 0,
            'other->other': 0
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            var ln = lines[i];

            // Luca Viggiani 2017-07-03: handle optional <?xml ... ?> declaration
            if (ln.match(/\s*<\?xml/)) {
                formatted += ln + "\n";
                continue;
            }
            // ---

            var single = Boolean(ln.match(/<.+\/>/)); // is this line a single tag? ex. <br />
            var closing = Boolean(ln.match(/<\/.+>/)); // is this a closing tag? ex. </a>
            var opening = Boolean(ln.match(/<[^!].*>/)); // is this even a tag (that's not <!something>)
            var type = single ? 'single' : closing ? 'closing' : opening ? 'opening' : 'other';
            var fromTo = lastType + '->' + type;
            lastType = type;
            var padding = '';

            indent += transitions[fromTo];
            for (var j = 0; j < indent; j++) {
                padding += '\t';
            }
            if (fromTo == 'opening->closing')
                formatted = formatted.substr(0, formatted.length - 1) + ln + '\n'; // substr removes line break (\n) from prev loop
            else
                formatted += padding + ln + '\n';
        }

        return formatted;
    };
```

Comment: could you please update your function to take into account Chuan Ma's comment below? Worked for me. Thanks. Edit: I just did it myself.

Comment: Hi, I've improved a little bit your function in order to correctly handle the optional `<?xml ... ?>` declaration at the beginning of the XML text

Answer (score 17):

Personnaly, I use [google-code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) with this function :

```
prettyPrintOne('<root><node1><root>', 'xml')
```

Comment: Oups, you need to indent XML and google-code-prettify only colorized the code. sorry.

Comment: combine prettify with smth like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java

Comment: That combined with http://code.google.com/p/vkbeautify/ for indentation made for a good combo.

Comment: Moved from google code to github.New link: https://github.com/google/code-prettify

Answer (score 9):

Or if you'd just like another js function to do it, I've modified Darin's (a lot):

```
var formatXml = this.formatXml = function (xml) {
    var reg = /(>)(<)(\/*)/g;
    var wsexp = / *(.*) +\n/g;
    var contexp = /(<.+>)(.+\n)/g;
    xml = xml.replace(reg, '$1\n$2$3').replace(wsexp, '$1\n').replace(contexp, '$1\n$2');
    var pad = 0;
    var formatted = '';
    var lines = xml.split('\n');
    var indent = 0;
    var lastType = 'other';
    // 4 types of tags - single, closing, opening, other (text, doctype, comment) - 4*4 = 16 transitions 
    var transitions = {
        'single->single'    : 0,
        'single->closing'   : -1,
        'single->opening'   : 0,
        'single->other'     : 0,
        'closing->single'   : 0,
        'closing->closing'  : -1,
        'closing->opening'  : 0,
        'closing->other'    : 0,
        'opening->single'   : 1,
        'opening->closing'  : 0, 
        'opening->opening'  : 1,
        'opening->other'    : 1,
        'other->single'     : 0,
        'other->closing'    : -1,
        'other->opening'    : 0,
        'other->other'      : 0
    };

    for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var ln = lines[i];
        var single = Boolean(ln.match(/<.+\/>/)); // is this line a single tag? ex. <br />
        var closing = Boolean(ln.match(/<\/.+>/)); // is this a closing tag? ex. </a>
        var opening = Boolean(ln.match(/<[^!].*>/)); // is this even a tag (that's not <!something>)
        var type = single ? 'single' : closing ? 'closing' : opening ? 'opening' : 'other';
        var fromTo = lastType + '->' + type;
        lastType = type;
        var padding = '';

        indent += transitions[fromTo];
        for (var j = 0; j < indent; j++) {
            padding += '    ';
        }

        formatted += padding + ln + '\n';
    }

    return formatted;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

All of the javascript functions given here won't work for an xml document having unspecified white spaces between the end tag '>' and the start tag '<'. To fix them, you just need to replace the first line in the functions

```
var reg = /(>)(<)(\/*)/g;
```

by

```
var reg = /(>)\s*(<)(\/*)/g;
```

Answer (score 5):

For a current project I had the need to prettify and colorize XML without extra libraries. The following self contained code works quite well.

```
function formatXml(xml,colorize,indent) { 
  function esc(s){return s.replace(/[-\/&<> ]/g,function(c){         // Escape special chars
    return c==' '?'&nbsp;':'&#'+c.charCodeAt(0)+';';});}            
  var sm='<div class="xmt">',se='<div class="xel">',sd='<div class="xdt">',
      sa='<div class="xat">',tb='<div class="xtb">',tc='<div class="xtc">',
      ind=indent||'  ',sz='</div>',tz='</div>',re='',is='',ib,ob,at,i;
  if (!colorize) sm=se=sd=sa=sz='';   
  xml.match(/(?<=<).*(?=>)|$/s)[0].split(/>\s*</).forEach(function(nd){
    ob=('<'+nd+'>').match(/^(<[!?\/]?)(.*?)([?\/]?>)$/s);             // Split outer brackets
    ib=ob[2].match(/^(.*?)>(.*)<\/(.*)$/s)||['',ob[2],''];            // Split inner brackets 
    at=ib[1].match(/^--.*--$|=|('|").*?\1|[^\t\n\f \/>"'=]+/g)||['']; // Split attributes
    if (ob[1]=='</') is=is.substring(ind.length);                     // Decrease indent
    re+=tb+tc+esc(is)+tz+tc+sm+esc(ob[1])+sz+se+esc(at[0])+sz;
    for (i=1;i<at.length;i++) re+=(at[i]=="="?sm+"="+sz+sd+esc(at[++i]):sa+' '+at[i])+sz;
    re+=ib[2]?sm+esc('>')+sz+sd+esc(ib[2])+sz+sm+esc('</')+sz+se+ib[3]+sz:'';
    re+=sm+esc(ob[3])+sz+tz+tz;
    if (ob[1]+ob[3]+ib[2]=='<>') is+=ind;                             // Increase indent
  });
  return re;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/dkb0La16/

Comment: Awesome solution, without any dependency! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

what about creating a stub node (document.createElement('div') - or using your library equivalent), filling it with the xml string (via innerHTML) and calling simple recursive function for the root element/or the stub element in case you don't have a root. The function would call itself for all the child nodes.

You could then syntax-highlight along the way, be certain the markup is well-formed (done automatically by browser when appending via innerHTML) etc. It wouldn't be that much code and probably fast enough.

Comment: Sounds like the outline for an amazing, elegant solution. How about an implementation?

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a JavaScript solution just take the code from the Pretty Diff tool at http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify

You can also send files to the tool using the s parameter, such as:
http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify&s=https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: prettydiff is a real nice tool. Here's some more info on usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822460/pretty-diff-usage/30648547#30648547

Answer (score 4):

You can get pretty formatted xml with [xml-beautify](https://github.com/riversun/xml-beautify)

```
var prettyXmlText = new XmlBeautify().beautify(xmlText, 
                    {indent: "  ",useSelfClosingElement: true});
```

**indent**:indent pattern like white spaces

**useSelfClosingElement**: true=>use self-closing element when empty element.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zr9s5fLn/8/)

Original(Before)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><example version="2.0">
  <head><title>Original aTitle</title></head>
  <body info="none" ></body>
</example>
```

Beautified(After)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<example version="2.0">
  <head>
    <title>Original aTitle</title>
  </head>
  <body info="none" />
</example>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Or just print out the special HTML characters?

Ex: <xmlstuff>&#10; &#09;<node />&#10;</xmlstuff>   


&#09;   Horizontal tab  
&#10;   Line feed
```

Answer (score 2):

[XMLSpectrum](https://github.com/pgfearo/xmlspectrum) formats XML, supports attribute indentation and also does syntax-highlighting for XML and any embedded XPath expressions:

[image: XMLSpectrum formatted XML]

XMLSpectrum is an open source project, coded in XSLT 2.0 - so you can run this server-side with a processor such as Saxon-HE (recommended) or client-side using Saxon-CE.

*XMLSpectrum is not yet optimised to run in the browser - hence the recommendation to run this server-side.*

Answer (score 2):

here is another function to format xml

```
function formatXml(xml){
    var out = "";
    var tab = "    ";
    var indent = 0;
    var inClosingTag=false;
    var dent=function(no){
        out += "\n";
        for(var i=0; i < no; i++)
            out+=tab;
    }


    for (var i=0; i < xml.length; i++) {
        var c = xml.charAt(i);
        if(c=='<'){
            // handle </
            if(xml.charAt(i+1) == '/'){
                inClosingTag = true;
                dent(--indent);
            }
            out+=c;
        }else if(c=='>'){
            out+=c;
            // handle />
            if(xml.charAt(i-1) == '/'){
                out+="\n";
                //dent(--indent)
            }else{
              if(!inClosingTag)
                dent(++indent);
              else{
                out+="\n";
                inClosingTag=false;
              }
            }
        }else{
          out+=c;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var formatXml = this.formatXml = function (xml) {
        var reg = /(>)(<)(\/*)/g;
        var wsexp = / *(.*) +\n/g;
        var contexp = /(<.+>)(.+\n)/g;
        xml = xml.replace(reg, '$1\n$2$3').replace(wsexp, '$1\n').replace(contexp, '$1\n$2');
        var pad = 0;
        var formatted = '';
        var lines = xml.split('\n');
        var indent = 0;
        var lastType = 'other';
```

Comment: After struggling with this poorly formed answer, I got it to work, I suppose--the results aren't very pretty: no indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Xml formatting can be done by parsing the xml, adding or changing text nodes in the dom tree for indentation and then serializing the DOM back to xml.

Please check **formatxml** function in https://jsonbrowser.sourceforge.io/formatxml.js
You can see the function in action in https://jsonbrowser.sourceforge.io/
under the Xml tab.

Below is the simplified code.
**formatxml.js** adds error checking, optional removal of comments, indent as a parameter and handles non-space text between parent nodes.

```
const parser = new DOMParser();

const serializer = new XMLSerializer();

function formatXml(xml) {
  let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');
  let rootElement = xmlDoc.documentElement;
  indentChildren(xmlDoc, rootElement, "\n", "\n  ");
  xml = serializer.serializeToString(xmlDoc);
  return xml;
}

function indentChildren(xmlDoc, node, prevPrefix, prefix) {
  let children = node.childNodes;
  let i;
  let prevChild = null;
  let prevChildType = 1;
  let child = null;
  let childType;
  for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    child = children[i];
    childType = child.nodeType;
    if (childType != 3) {
      if (prevChildType == 3) {
        // Update prev text node with correct indent
        prevChild.nodeValue = prefix;
      } else {
        // Create and insert text node with correct indent
        let textNode = xmlDoc.createTextNode(prefix);
        node.insertBefore(textNode, child);
        i++;
      }
      if (childType == 1) {
        let isLeaf = child.childNodes.length == 0 || child.childNodes.length == 1 && child.childNodes[0].nodeType != 1;
        if (!isLeaf) {
          indentChildren(xmlDoc, child, prefix, prefix + "  ");
        }
      }
    }
    prevChild = child;
    prevChildType =childType;
  }
  if (child != null) {
    // Previous level indentation after last child
    if (childType == 3) {
      child.nodeValue = prevPrefix;
    } else {
      let textNode = xmlDoc.createTextNode(prevPrefix);
      node.append(textNode);
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/XML/dom_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg = /(>)\s*(<)(\/*)/g;
xml = xml.replace(/\r|\n/g, ''); //deleting already existing whitespaces
xml = xml.replace(reg, '$1\r\n$2$3');
```

Comment: This does not add indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use above method for pretty print and then add this in any div by using jquery **text()** method. for example id of div is `xmldiv` then use :

`$("#xmldiv").text(formatXml(youXmlString));`

Comment: What "above method for pretty print"?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Saxon-JS client-side:

```js
<script src="SaxonJS/SaxonJS2.js"></script>

<script>
let myXML = `<root><node/></root>`;

SaxonJS.getResource({
   text: myXML.replace(`xml:space="preserve"`, ''),
   type: "xml"
}).then(doc => {
   const output = SaxonJS.serialize(doc, {method: "xml", indent: true, "omit-xml-declaration":true});
   console.log(output);
})
</script>
```

[Saxon-JS Installation client-side](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/index.html#!starting/installing)
[Saxon-JS Download page](https://www.saxonica.com/download/javascript.xml)

Answer (score 0):

This may involve creating nodes as objects, but you can have total control over exporting pretty formatted xml.

The following will return a string array of the lines which you can join with a new line delimiter "\n".

```
/**
 * The child of an XML node can be raw text or another xml node.
 */
export type PossibleNode = XmlNode | string;

/**
 * Base XML Node type.
 */
export interface XmlNode {
  tag: string;
  attrs?: { [key: string]: string };
  children?: PossibleNode[];
}

/**
 * Exports the given XML node to a string array.
 * 
 * @param node XML Node
 * @param autoClose Auto close the tag
 * @param indent Indentation level
 * @returns String array
 */
export function xmlNodeToString(
  node: XmlNode,
  autoClose: boolean = true,
  indent: number = 0
): string[] {
  const indentStr = " ".repeat(indent);
  const sb: string[] = [];
  sb.push(`${indentStr}<${node.tag}`);
  if (node.attrs) {
    for (const key in node.attrs) {
      sb.push(`${indentStr} ${key}="${node.attrs[key]}"`);
    }
  }
  if (node.children) {
    if (node.children.length === 1 && typeof node.children[0] === "string") {
      sb[sb.length - 1] += ">" + node.children[0];
    } else {
      sb.push(`${indentStr}>`);
      for (const child of node.children) {
        if (typeof child === "string") {
          sb.push(`${indentStr}  ${child}`);
        } else {
          const lines = xmlNodeToString(child, autoClose, indent + 1);
          sb.push(...lines.map((line) => `${indentStr}  ${line}`));
        }
      }
    }
    if (autoClose) {
      if (node.children.length === 1 && typeof node.children[0] === "string") {
        sb[sb.length - 1] += `</${node.tag}>`;
      } else {
        sb.push(`${indentStr}</${node.tag}>`);
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (autoClose) {
      sb.push(`${indentStr}/>`);
    } else {
      sb.push(`${indentStr}>`);
    }
  }
  return sb;
}
```

Updates appreciated on the gist: https://gist.github.com/rodydavis/acd609560ab0416b60681fddabc43eee

Answer (score -1):

[Xml-to-json](https://github.com/javadev/xml-to-json) library has method `formatXml(xml).` I am the maintainer of the project.

```
var prettyXml = formatXml("<a><b/></a>");

// <a>
//   <b/>
// </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

This my version, maybe usefull for others, using String builder
Saw that someone had the same piece of code.

```
    public String FormatXml(String xml, String tab)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        int indent = 0;
        // find all elements
        foreach (string node in Regex.Split(xml,@">\s*<"))
        {
            // if at end, lower indent
            if (Regex.IsMatch(node, @"^\/\w")) indent--;
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}<{1}>", string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(tab, indent).ToArray()), node));
            // if at start, increase indent
            if (Regex.IsMatch(node, @"^<?\w[^>]*[^\/]$")) indent++;
        }
        // correct first < and last > from the output
        String result = sb.ToString().Substring(1);
        return result.Remove(result.Length - Environment.NewLine.Length-1);
    }
```

Comment: The question asks about a JavaScript solution, but this is C# code.