# Print xml in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I tryed to use answer from [How to print pretty xml in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187451/how-to-print-pretty-xml-in-javascript) but it didnt work for my code. It prints [object]. Is there some way to print xml in this  object?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="loadxmldoc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>

var xmldoc= loadXMLDoc('skoly.xml');

var d = document.createElement('div'); 
var t = document.createTextNode(xmldoc); 
d.appendChild(t);
document.write('<pre>' + d.innerHTML + '</pre>');


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

loadxmldoc.js:

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // code for IE5 and IE6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

Comment: The second answer in that thread looks a lot more promising than the accepted answer. Try that instead.

Comment: What does skoly.xml look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty printing XML with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The `responseXML` property will return an object of type `Document` if it is able to, otherwise `null` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#responseXML).

If all you're trying to do with the returned XML is to print it as text, you're probably best off just using the `responseText` property on the `xhttp` object instead, which will give you the XML as a string of text (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#responseText).

Your code for loadxmldoc.js should then become;

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // code for IE5 and IE6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseText;
}
```

Also, as a side note, it's not really recommended to use synchronous XMLHttpRequests, since this blocks the main thread. As explained further on in that article ([https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29)), this will be deprecated from FF 30