# Coldfusion - XML Pretty Print

Tags: xml, coldfusion, pretty-print

There are a lot of ways to pretty print XML, but I have yet to find one using a ColdFusion function.

This is a common question, but again I want to do this within ColdFusion.

Comment: When there's no ColdFusion solution, there will almost always have a Java solution.  Just consume it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search on http://cflib.org turned up [xmlIndent()](http://cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=2057).

```
<pre>#xmlIndent(xmlString)#</pre>
```

Comment: It's says the stuff at cflib.org is 'open source', but this can mean different things to different people.  Is there a license they use, or is it free as in free for both commercial and and non-commercial use?

Comment: My understanding is that it is free as in both beer and speech.  If you are concerned, you can contact the author from the UDF page.

Comment: I tried this and it failed on the 2nd XML string that I tested it with. Built-in JDOM can generate pretty-print string, but it only works with Adobe ColdFusion 10+ (not Lucee CFML.)

Answer (score 1):

see top answer of: [Pretty printing XML with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript).  Try it with `XmlTransform()`.  If it doesn't work, pick a Java XSLT engine like http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ as suggested

Answer (score 0):

I use a Java solution [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/) for this purpose, so you'd need to have its jar in your classpath for it work. [Following answer in original Java code](https://xom.dev.java.net/source/browse/xom/src/nu/xom/samples/PrettyPrinter.java?rev=HEAD&only_with_tag=MAIN):

```
<cfset xmlString = [your xml here]/>

<cfscript>
encoding = "ISO-8859-1";
parser = createObject("java", "nu.xom.Builder").init();
doc = parser.build(xmlString);
out = createObject("java", "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream").init();
Serializer serializer = new Serializer(out, encoding);
// bunch of options
serializer.setIndent(4);
serializer.setMaxLength(64);
serializer.setPreserveBaseURI(true);

serializer.write(doc);
serializer.flush();
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>#out.toString(encoding)#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use prettydiff.com/markup_beauty.js.  If it is capable of supporting invalid markup, fragments, and JSTL code then it should be able to handle CFML without any burden.  Consider the following example of a complex JSTL tag.

```
<c:out value="<strong>text</strong>"/>
```

You can demo that application using a web tool at [prettydiff.com](http://prettydiff.com/).  Just choose the "beautify" and "markup" options.

Answer (score 0):

If using Adobe ColdFusion, the java [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) library is already built-in and can generate pretty-print XML from an XML string or XML object.

I [modernized a UDF](https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/f4db70dd266b6640f4e6adc302d062db) from 2010 to use CFScript and only output a prettyprint string if XML is valid. It works with ColdFusion 10-2021, but not Lucee CFML.

```
<cfscript>
string function prettyXml(required any xml) hint="I convert valid XML (string or object) to a pretty-print XML string" {
    if (isxml(arguments.xml)){
        local.xmlstring = createobject("java", "java.io.StringReader").init(javacast("string", arguments.xml));
        local.document = createobject("java", "org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder").init().build(local.xmlstring);
    } else if (isxmldoc(arguments.xml)){
        local.document = createobject("java", "org.jdom.input.DOMBuilder").init().build(arguments.xml);
    } else return "";
    local.format = createobject("java", "org.jdom.output.Format").getPrettyFormat();
    local.out = createobject("java", "org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter").init(local.format);
    return local.out.outputString(local.document);
}
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

[CommandBox](https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox) has a function that uses CFML's built-in [xmlTransform](https://cfdocs.org/xmltransform) function to generate pretty-print XML. It can accept an object or a string and works on any CFML platform.

https://github.com/Ortus-Solutions/commandbox/blob/development/src/cfml/system/util/Formatter.cfc#L273-L290

```
/**
* Pretty print XML
* @XMLDoc A string containing XML or a parsed XML document
*/
function formatXML( XMLDoc ) {
    var xlt = '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" xslt:indent-amount="2" xmlns:xslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" /></xsl:copy></xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>';
    var XMLDeclaration = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
    try {
        return toString( XmlTransform( XMLDoc, xlt) ).replace( XMLDeclaration, '', 'once' );
    } catch( any e ) {
        return toString( XMLDoc ).replace( XMLDeclaration, '', 'once' );
    }
}
```