# format xml, pretty print

Tags: xml, pretty-print, prettify

I know of two ways to "pretty print", or format, xml:

1. [shell tools](http://www.shell-tools.net/)
2. [Hack 38 Pretty-Print XML Using a Generic Identity Stylesheet and Xalan](http://etutorials.org/XML/xml+hacks/Chapter+3.+Transforming+XML+Documents/Hack+38+Pretty-Print+XML+Using+a+Generic+Identity+Stylesheet+and+Xalan/)

what other free (as in beer) formatters are there?  (aside from using javascript)

Comment: Just for completeness and better discoverability I link to [pretty printing xml with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript) (which is probably the canonical SO thread regarding javascript solutions to this problem)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, the identity transform you linked to is portable to any XSLT processor (Saxon, msxml, etc).

Additionally, you could look at `xmllint` which is part of the [LibXML2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) toolkit. The `--format` option allows you to pretty print the input.  Similar functionality exists in [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) (which uses LibXML2 under the hood iirc).

Comment: Works great for strings too: `echo "<xml here>" | xmllint --format -`

Answer (score 11):

`xmlstarlet fo` is what I use for pretty printing. [Xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) has a number of options:

```
$ xmlstarlet fo --help
XMLStarlet Toolkit: Format XML document
Usage: xml fo [<options>] <xml-file>
where <options> are
  -n or --noindent            - do not indent
  -t or --indent-tab          - indent output with tabulation
  -s or --indent-spaces <num> - indent output with <num> spaces
  -o or --omit-decl           - omit xml declaration <?xml version="1.0"?>
  -R or --recover             - try to recover what is parsable
  -D or --dropdtd             - remove the DOCTYPE of the input docs
  -C or --nocdata             - replace cdata section with text nodes
  -N or --nsclean             - remove redundant namespace declarations
  -e or --encode <encoding>   - output in the given encoding (utf-8, unicode...)
  -H or --html                - input is HTML
```

A good XML engineer should be able to wield xmlstarlet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify
Unfortunately, it is written in JavaScript, but it is a complete application so you never have to know that.  Just know that you can run from inside your browser without downloading or installing anything.

Answer (score 1):

I like the java library [XOM](http://www.xom.nu) for XML manipulation. It has a nice [Pretty Printer](https://github.com/elharo/xom/blob/master/src/nu/xom/samples/PrettyPrinter.java) that provides a lot of control over the output.

Answer (score 0):

When using libxml2 in python:

```
with open(pathToSaveResult, 'w') as fd:
   xmlParsed.saveTo(fd,format = libxml2.XML_SAVE_FORMAT)
```

Edit: It looks like there is some bug in libxml2 ...pretty printing is done with the tag  libxml2.XML_SAVE_NO_EMPTY instead of  libxml2.XML_SAVE_FORMAT