# javascript pretty html

Tags: javascript, html, prettify

Is there a javascript library that can make bad html readable?

For example:

```
<div><span></span></div>
```

into

```
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You may checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript as said Darin

Comment: alright everyone, flag to close!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firebug on FireFox, HTML is all laid out nicely in the HTML pane.

Depends if you want to reasd it, or save it in a readable form (which Firebug won't)

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to ident your code, use your favorite ide. If it is eclipse, the shortcut is something like ctrl + shift + f

Comment: I'm pretty sure that @mark is looking for a JS library to format HTML in a web browser not a text editor.