# Displaying XML with IE IFRAMES

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, iframe

I am working with some software that sends and receives XML... and for debugging purposes it's obviously helpful to look at what's getting passed back and forth. IE does a great job of word wrapping and formatting SINGLE xml files... but I am kinda stuck on how to apply the same functionality to iframes in an HTML page.

Load up an XML file in IE... I want to do this with dynamically generated XML (3 sometimes 4 or 5 xml files) inline for debugging purposes.

I tried the following:

```
<iframe width="800" height="600"><xml><node>stuff</node></xml></iframe>
```

But that just shows an empty iframe. I am also wrapping my XML in  tags right now... and for some reason the XML just doesn't show up on the page.

Any suggestions better than copy/pasting the XML into a file and opening it in IE every time I want to look at my request/response XML?

Comment: the iframe must alays point to a file. As far as I'm aware, you can't just drop code into an iframe to view it.

Answer (score 1):

iframe can have `src` element which may point to a file, so copy & pasta it programaticlly ( dump output to a file and point iframe to id )

Comment: I tried outputting the xml into the src="" attribute but that just made IE show the "page cannot be found" error. If I can avoid it I don't want to create a bunch of extra files I'll have to remember to delete later.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending and receiving the XML over HTTP, I'd use a HTTP viewer (sniffer) to see the request and responses in real time.

I tend to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for this kind of thing.

Comment: Very cool freeware program I like it a lot... unfortunately this won't display XML nicely like IE does. I see a single request that generates all my xml... in the inspectors tab there's even an "XML" tab but because the response isn't 100% xml I guess it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try some of the suggestions from this question: [Pretty printing XML with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript)