# How to format XML code in Ace Editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am using ACE Editor to display xml content on my web page. I want to format the xml code in Editor.

Can Any one tell me how to do this ?

Comment: I HAVE APPLIED editor.session.setFoldStyle("markbeginend");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous modes included in the package and the [Wiki at github](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki) will tell you how to implement it. Something like this:

```
var Mode = require('ace/mode/xml').Mode;
editor.getSession().setMode(new Mode());
```

Comment: i have used xml mode but i want something that can format xml content displayed in editor. Something which can work same as "Ctrl+shift+F" in eclipse to format code.

Comment: Why did you accept the answer, if it does not answer your question?

Answer (score 15):

XML Code formatting is not specified in Ace itself, as it's just an editor. Use any of the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript) to prettify the code.

```
var code = ace.getSession().getValue();
// prettify
ace.getSession().setValue(code);
```