# How to read XML dynamically using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I know how to read an XML using an ajax request and making use of text() and nodename. But what i want is reading any XML dynamically so that,it automatically reads all the tags and values and can display the XML in the form a tree structure. Suggestions using javascript are also welcome.Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pretty printing XML with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript)