# How to skip line with x2js?

Tags: json, xml, angularjs

I'm using angularjs to develop my application. I use a JSON variable which I want to convert into xml. I do it with the following code :

My JSON variable :

```
variableJSON = {
    "content": {
      "section": []
    },
    "field": {
      "string": [],
      "integer": [],
      "decimal": [],
      "list": [],
      "iterator": []
    },
  };
```

I fill it when my application run.
And this is my code to convert it :

```
x2js = new X2JS({
    escapeMode: false,
  });

var xmlVar = $scope.x2js.json2xml_str(variableJSON);
```

This is an adaptation. My real code isn't like this so it's possible it's not working with the code here.
Finally I have this :

```
<content><section id='S0'><label lang='en'>Section 1</label><single name='Q0'><label lang='en'>Question 1</label></single></section></content><field></field>
```

As you can see, there is only one line. I would like to skip line for each different tags to have a proper view of what I generated. But I don't want to do it after the generation. When the XML is generated I must keep it intact. I couldn't find a solution on x2js website or on any forum. 

Do you have a solution to skip line during the XML generation ? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the mentioned `xml2json` is [x2js](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/). If this is true, then there is no way to *indent* the resulting XML.

The best options for you are:

1. Use another JSON to XML library that has the option for indentation.
2. Use some pretty printing library that will format your one-line XML into indented XML.
   (see [Pretty printing XML with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript) for example)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I'll try both solutions.