# Preview Xml data or Json object as XML tree in Html with Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Json object or xml Data that I would like to preview this in html as React is doing: https://github.com/marushkevych/xml-display-component
but I don't want to mix Javascript and Reactjs.
I hope someone can help me.

Example of my Xml: 
I want this to show as a tree , as the same xml format.[Click to see the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpQvw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like the vkBeautify Plugin.

http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkbeautify/

Or maybe write your own formatting logic.

If I get it right, you want to pretty print XML and JSON Data as HTML in a Webbrowser with Javascript.

Take a look at this Question: [Pretty printing XML with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I can use a pretty print too that vkBeautify Plugin is doing. 
But I was looking for a module because I'd like to preview the xml with the possibility to show it as a Tree.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marushkevych/xml-display-component/master/exmple.png

Comment: Try sth else... like_ http://www.levmuchnik.net/Content/ProgrammingTips/WEB/XMLDisplay/DisplayXMLFileWithJavascript.html

Comment: Thanks. But I don't have a static file, the xml is generated on Server . I think I need to build my logic...
I am trying to find some modules and nothing, the only way I found React but Idk if is a good idea mix with React.
Otherwise I can find a module to make Trees and modify it to implement xml tags.
What do you think?

Comment: Did you see the LoadXmlString() Function?
http://www.levmuchnik.net/Content/ProgrammingTips/WEB/XMLDisplay/DisplayXMLFileWithJavascript.html#Usage

Comment: I guess it ist exactly what you are looking for...

http://www.levmuchnik.net/Content/ProgrammingTips/WEB/XMLDisplay/XMLDisplay.js

AND

http://www.levmuchnik.net/Content/ProgrammingTips/WEB/XMLDisplay/XMLDisplay.css

Comment: Hey Yes, THANKS, I was spending time trying to realise where to find the loadXmlString() function. and you got it.
I am going to try this code. I will let you know how is going.

Comment: It's going great. Thanks