# Display XML in HTML with proper indentation

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

So i have gone through some example where XML is static and that can be displayed using pre , code and textarea tag.

my real problem is i am generating xml as string in jquery which looks like below

```
string str = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><items><item><Name>c</Name><Value>a</value></item><item><Name>b</Name><Value>b</value></item><item><Name>a</Name><Value>c</value></item><item></items>"
```

now i want to display this string as proper xml indentation like below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<items>
 <item>
  <Name>c</Name>
  <Value>a</value>
 </item>
 <item>
  <Name>b</Name>
  <Value>b</value>
 </item>
 <item>
  <Name>a</Name>
  <Value>c</value>
 </item>
</items>
```

what should be the best approach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript