# Pretty print XML content from a service in a panel SAPIU5/Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5, pretty-print, payload

I have a Payload with xml content(from a service) and I have a expand/collapse panel on witch I click and display by binding in a label the content of that payload.

The problem is that is not displaying the stuff in a prettyprint standard xml format but it puts everything random like one stuff after another.

How do I pretty print the content to be something like this after I expand the panel:

```
<bookstore>
  <book category="children">
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title>Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>

and not something like this:

<bookstore>
  <book category="children"><title>Harry Potter</title><author>J K.Rowling</author><year>2005</year>    .....</bookstore>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty printing XML with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective this is a misuse of Label control. Try [m.FormattedText](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.FormattedText/preview) or [m.Text](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Text/preview)

Comment: I think I have to use vkbeautify library but I don't know very well hot to use it. I'm trying to do something right now.