# Pentaho Kettle Group by with type concatenate produces duplicates

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

I have following Excel file:

[image: Excel sheet screenshot]

My end result should looks like (example of output file for first entry):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asset>
    <asset_feature key="ItemID" value="12000"/>
    <asset_feature key="Name" value="Name of the first item"/>
    <asset_feature key="Price" value="1020.0"/>
</asset>
```

In order to achieve it on initial steps I use `Row Normaliser` step and after it `Group by` with type `Concatenate strings separated by ,`. I am expecting to have this:

```
<asset_feature key="ItemID" value="12000"/>, <asset_feature key="Name" value="Name of the first item"/>, <asset_feature key="Price" value="1020.0"/>
```

and use technic from `XML Add - creating multi level XML files` example for `>, <` replacement, as: `var xmlOutput=xmlOrderListNew.replace(">, <","><");`, but instead I get following result back (3 duplicated rows):

```
<asset_feature key="ItemID" value="12000"/>, <asset_feature key="Name" value="Name of the first item"/>, <asset_feature key="Price" value="1020.0"/>
<asset_feature key="ItemID" value="12000"/>, <asset_feature key="Name" value="Name of the first item"/>, <asset_feature key="Price" value="1020.0"/>
<asset_feature key="ItemID" value="12000"/>, <asset_feature key="Name" value="Name of the first item"/>, <asset_feature key="Price" value="1020.0"/>
```

so, to fix it I have to put extra transformation step for getting just `Unique rows`. Transformation picture:

[image: Transformation flow]

**Question is**: how to fix `Group by` step to don't get duplicates without extra `Unique rows` step, as `XML Add - creating multi level XML files` doesn't have such issue?

**Optional question 1**: is there any simple way for concatenation in order to avoid `replace(">, <","><")` step later?

**Optional question 2**: How to make pretty XML (with indentation) formatting?

Example Excel & transformation are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1A31cn7Dgg-HQW_pNCPCm6B-4s2WabXw_?usp=sharing)

Thank you in advice for your help.

Comment: Un-check the `Include all row  check box !

Comment: Use a `Concatenate string separated by` (without coma) and do not put anything as `value`.

Comment: You can put any function in a javascript step. In particular you can copy a xml pretty printer, for example https://gist.github.com/sente/1083506/d2834134cd070dbcc08bf42ee27dabb746a1c54d.

Comment: Use `Memory group by` rather than `Group by`

Comment: Thank you @AlainD. All proposed by you solutions work. For Pretty print I have found out another way with XSLT here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript The rest works. Strange that when I have played with `Include all row` checkbox before it didn't work for me, but now is fine. One more question: what is the performance benefit of `Memory group by` against `Group by` let say on 1M lines with not 3 (like in example) but 100 key-value pairs?

Comment: @AlainD: please, post your comments as an answer which I can accept as a correct one. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 0 (Avoid duplicate in group by): Un-check the `Include all row check box`!

Question 1 (Avoid "," in concatenation): Use a `Concatenate string separated by` (without coma) and do not put anything as `value`.

Question 2 (Petty print xml/html): You can put any function in a javascript step. In particular you can copy a xml pretty printer, for example [formatXML.js](https://gist.github.com/sente/1083506/d2834134cd070dbcc08bf42ee27dabb746a1c54d)

Un-asked question: Use `Memory Group by` rather than `Group by` step, unless you have really really huge data.