# undefined: undefined error when calling XSLTProcessor.prototype.importStylesheet

Tags: javascript, firefox, xslt, domparser

I want to prettify some XML, and I found following code ([in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47317538/607407), [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/klesun/sgeryvyu/5/)). I modified it like this:

```
const xsltDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString([
    // describes how we want to modify the XML - indent everything
    '<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">',
    '  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>',
    '    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">',
    '      <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>',
    '    </xsl:template>',
    '</xsl:stylesheet>',
].join('\n'), 'application/xml');
function prettifyXml(sourceXml) {
    var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(sourceXml, 'application/xml');
    var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    // Error happens here:
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);
    var resultDoc = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlDoc);
    var resultXml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDoc);
    return resultXml;
};
```

I get an error running the code, but the error has no message. It looks like this in Firefox console:

[image]

And this is what I see in debugger:

[image]

**The error does also happen in the Fiddle from the original answer.** I would like to know what kind of error is this and how to fix it.

I am including Firefox tag, because I think this is not a normal browser behavior. My version is 61.0.2 (64-bit).

Answer (score 6):

In terms of XSLT you need a `version` attribute on the root element of the stylesheet so try `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">`. This seems to fix the error on the `importStylesheet` call, see https://jsfiddle.net/sgeryvyu/361/.

On the other hand, Firefox/Mozilla's XSLT processor is known to do a tree to tree transformation so with `transformToDocument` and Mozilla you won't get any serialization options of `xsl:output` applied, meaning that attempt to push your DOM tree through an XSLT simply gives you another DOM tree without the wanted indentation.