# After insert Node to XML formating

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, domparser

I add a new node to an existing XML but the format is not well.
Original XML is:

```
<xml xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

   <vars>
....
```

I tried to insert before "vars" and the result is

```
<xml xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

    <TCafe initvalue="1" type="int"/><vars>
```

But I expect

```
<xml xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

    <TCafe initvalue="1" type="int"/>

       <vars>
```

My code is simple:

```
var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(dataRegelWerk);
if(allok == false){
                var root = xmlDoc.documentElement;

                var varselem = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('vars')[0];
                var newEle = xmlDoc.createElement('TCafe');
                var att1 = xmlDoc.createAttribute("initvalue");
                att1.value = "1";
                var att2 = xmlDoc.createAttribute("type");
                att2.value = "int";
                newEle.setAttributeNode(att1);
                newEle.setAttributeNode(att2);

                root.insertBefore(newEle, varselem);
            }

var myFile = serializer.serializeToString(xmlDoc);
```

Do I understand something wrong with insertBefore? or is this a good XML formatting and I just expect a wrong thing?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript

Comment: Thank you, but I do not think that I have to reformat an existing XML document.  In my exes the Nodejs xmldim module has bugs