# Why isnt my simple calculator postman request not working?

Tags: python, web-services, soap, postman

Im new to postman and web services and i am trying to implement a simple calculator web service using postman and a wsdl.The problem is i dont know how to send request via body or header of postman.
[image]

[image]
[image]

My python code is:
from spyne import Application, rpc, ServiceBase, Integer, Double
from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication

```
class CalculatorService(ServiceBase):

    @rpc(Integer, Integer, _returns=Integer)
    def addition(ctx, a, b):
        return a + b

    @rpc(Integer, Integer, _returns=Integer)
    def substraction(ctx, a, b):
        return a - b

    @rpc(Integer, Integer, _returns=Integer)
    def multiplication(ctx, a, b):
        return a * b

    @rpc(Integer, Integer, _returns=Double)
    def division(ctx, a, b):
        return a / b


application = Application([CalculatorService], 'services.calculator.soap',
                          in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
                          out_protocol=Soap11())

wsgi_application = WsgiApplication(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging

    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logging.getLogger('spyne.protocol.xml').setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logging.info("listening to http://127.0.0.1:8000")
    logging.info("wsdl is at: http://127.0.0.1:8000/?wsdl")

    server = make_server('127.0.0.1', 8000, wsgi_application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Tried completing the header parametres but cant seem to get why it isnt functioning.

Comment: What does your headers look like? Please add a screenshot of the headers tab (postman)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a input parameters <a> and <b> and name service `services.calculator.soap`.

This is addition input

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="services.calculator.soap">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:addition>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:a>6</ser:a>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:b>9</ser:b>
      </ser:addition>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

[image]

SoapUI make life easier.
Here is steps

#### #1 Python code save as `simple-calculator.py`

```
from spyne import Application, rpc, ServiceBase, Integer, Double

from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication

class CalculatorService(ServiceBase):

    @rpc(Integer, Integer, _returns=Integer)
    def addition(ctx, a, b):
        return a + b

    @rpc(Integer, Integer, _returns=Integer)
    def substraction(ctx, a, b):
        return a - b

    @rpc(Integer, Integer, _returns=Integer)
    def multiplication(ctx, a, b):
        return a * b

    @rpc(Integer, Integer, _returns=Double)
    def division(ctx, a, b):
        return a / b


application = Application([CalculatorService], 'services.calculator.soap',
                          in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
                          out_protocol=Soap11())

wsgi_application = WsgiApplication(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging

    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logging.getLogger('spyne.protocol.xml').setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logging.info("listening to http://127.0.0.1:8000")
    logging.info("wsdl is at: http://127.0.0.1:8000/?wsdl")

    server = make_server('127.0.0.1', 8000, wsgi_application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

#### #2 Install & Run it

```
pip install spyne
python simple-calculator.py
```

#### #3 Check WSDL is working by browser.

```
http://localhost:8000/?wsdl
```

[image]

#### #4 Create SOAP project by SoapUI

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### #5 Create SOAP input XML by clicking `Request 1` of `addition`

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="services.calculator.soap">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:addition>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:a>?</ser:a>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:b>?</ser:b>
      </ser:addition>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

[image]

#### #6 Run it after enter input of <a> and <b>, then press green run button

The result will return in right side of panel.
If you copy/pasted it (right side a red box) into VS Code and format document.
It will be more readable pretty format.

[image]

Before

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="services.calculator.soap"><soap11env:Body><tns:additionResponse><tns:additionResult>13</tns:additionResult></tns:additionResponse></soap11env:Body></soap11env:Envelope>
```

After

```
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="services.calculator.soap">
    <soap11env:Body>
        <tns:additionResponse>
            <tns:additionResult>15</tns:additionResult>
        </tns:additionResponse>
    </soap11env:Body>
</soap11env:Envelope>
```

#### Same steps for `division`, `multiplication` and `subtraction`

The `division` in Postman

[image]

#### References

[Work with WSDLs in SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls/)

[spyne examples](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/tree/master/examples)