# How can I make Soap api call from node js using soap npm

Tags: node.js, soap, soap-client, sabre

I tried to use "soap" npm and build an object to be sent as param but the object is not able to be converted to envelope. I posted the file and response below
**app.js file contain the below**

```
            var soap = require('soap');
            const express = require('express');
            const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
            
            var app = express();
            app.use(bodyParser.json());
            const url = 'https://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/shopping/SSSAdvShopRQ_v5-4-0.wsdl';
            
            let params = {
                Envelope: {
                    Header: {
                        Action:"SSSAdvShopRQ",
                        Security: {
                            BinarySecurityToken: "Token"
                        },
                        MessageHeader: {
                            From: {.
                                PartyId:[ "WebServiceClient"]
                            },
                            To: {
                                PartyId:[ "WebServiceSupplier"]
                            },
                            CPAId: "ET",
                            ConversationId: "TestSession",
                            Service: "SSSAdvShop",
                            Action: "SSSAdvShopRQ"
                        },
                    },
                    Body: {
                        OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ: {
                            POS: {
                                Source: {
                                    RequestorID: {
                                        CompanyName: {
                                        Code: "SSW"
                                        },
                                    Type: "1",
                                    ID: "1"
                                    },
                                PseudoCityCode: "ADD"
                                }
                            },
                            OriginDestinationInformation: [
                                {
                                    DepartureDateTime: "2023-01-25T00:00:00",
                                    OriginLocation: {
                                    LocationCode: "ADD"
                                    },
                                    DestinationLocation: {
                                    LocationCode: "DXB"
                                    },
                                    TPA_Extensions: "",
                                RPH: "1"
                                },
                                {
                                    DepartureDateTime: "2023-01-31T00:00:00",
                                    OriginLocation: {
                                    LocationCode: "DXB"
                                    },
                                    DestinationLocation: {
                                    LocationCode: "SEA"
                                    },
                                    TPA_Extensions: "",
                                RPH: "2"
                                }
                            ],
                            TravelPreferences: "",
                            TravelerInfoSummary: {
                                AirTravelerAvail: {
                                    PassengerTypeQuantity: {
                                    Code: "ADT",
                                    Quantity: "1"
                                    }
                                },
                                PriceRequestInformation: {
                                    TPA_Extensions: {
                                        Indicators: {
                                            RetainFare: {
                                            Ind: "true"
                                            },
                                            MinMaxStay: {
                                            Ind: "true"
                                            },
                                            RefundPenalty: {
                                            Ind: "true"
                                            },
                                            ResTicketing: {
                                            Ind: "true"
                                            },
                                            TravelPolicy: {
                                            Ind: "true"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        PointOfSaleOverride: {
                                        Code: "ADD"
                                        }
                                    },
                                CurrencyCode: "ETB"
                                }
                            },
                            TPA_Extensions: {
                                IntelliSellTransaction: {
                                    RequestType: {
                                    Name: "ADVBRD"
                                    },
                                    ServiceTag: {
                                    Name: "ET"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        Version: "5.4.0"
                                    },
                    }
                }
            };
            
            app.get('/', function (req, res) {
                soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
                    client.SSSAdvShopRQAsync(params, function (err, response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    res.status(200).send(response.data);
                    });
                });
            });
            
            
            app.listen(3000, () => {
                console.log("Server started at port 3000");
            });
```

**I get the below response**

soap-env:Fault
soap-env:Client.InvalidEbXmlMessage
Missing <soap-env:Header> in <soap-env:Envelope>  

javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Missing <soap-env:Header> in <soap-env:Envelope>

</soap-env:Fault>

I am looking how to convert from object to request envelope.

Comment: [WSDL URL](https://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/shoppin/SSSAdvShopRQ_v5-4-0.wsdl) makes 404 error (That file couldn't be found) can you make correct URL?

Comment: here is the WSDL "https://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/shopping/SSSAdvShopRQ_v5-4-0.wsdl"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no token and username/password. I can't test this API.

But I can suggest your try this steps.

#1 Find correct input data parameters before node.js call using `soapUI`.

This is detail information for [using simple calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75063294/why-isnt-my-simple-calculator-postman-request-not-working/75064595#75064595).

Example: You need to enter this values

```
<sec:Username>your user name</sec:Username>
<sec:Password>your user password</sec:Password>
<sec:BinarySecurityToken>real binary token</sec:BinarySecurityToken>
```

#2 Then resume node.js without express

This is detail information for [soap-npm node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74890978/how-to-consume-soap-web-services-using-node-js/74894011#74894011).

In `I found more easy way to consume SOAP service` section.

#3 With express

Comment: @Samuel Wakuma, thank for your accepting. Now you ca upvote me as over 15 reputation point, Can you Upvote too me. It makes me 10 points more.