How can I prettify/syntax-hilight xml in the browser using prettier?
I am looking at this example that describes how one can format graphql in the browser.
e.g.
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prettier@3.2.5/standalone.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prettier@3.2.5/plugins/graphql.js"></script>
<script>
  (async () => {
    const formatted = await prettier.format("type Query { hello: String }", {
      parser: "graphql",
      plugins: prettierPlugins,
    });
  })();
</script>

I am trying to do the same for xml, but from the corresponding cdn page, https://unpkg.com/prettier@3.2.5/plugins/ I do not know which plugin I should use.
I 've seen that there is prettier/plugin-xml but I cannot find a way to use it in the browser without using a bundler.

Consider using native tools: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript

@Justinas I want to print the xml with syntax highlighting somewhere inside the document.

Use highliter: https://highlightjs.org/
