# Java/DOM: Get the XML content of a node

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am parsing a XML file in Java using the W3C DOM.
I am stuck at a specific problem, I can't figure out how to get the whole inner XML of a node.

The node looks like that:

```
<td><b>this</b> is a <b>test</b></td>
```

What function do I have to use to get that:

```
"<b>this</b> is a <b>test</b>"
```

Comment: [This post on SO may help to get the inner Xml of a node ][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910474/how-to-get-node-contents-from-jdom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the transform/xslt API using your <b> node as the node to be transformed and put the result into a  new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
. See [how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java)

Answer (score 4):

I know this was asked long ago but for the next person searching (was me today), this works with JDOM:

```
JDOMXPath xpath = new JDOMXPath("/td");
String innerXml = (new XMLOutputter()).outputString(xpath.selectNodes(document));
```

This passes a list of all child nodes into outputString, which will serialize them out in order.

Answer (score 1):

er... you could also call toString() and just chop off the beginning and end tags, either manually or using regexps.

edit: toString() doesn't do what I expected. Pulling out the O'Reilly [Java & XML book](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZOlQAAAAMAAJ) talks about the Load and Save module of Java DOM.

See in particular the [LSSerializer](https://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html) which looks very promising. You could either call writeToString(node) and chop off the beginning and end tags, as I suggested, or try to use [LSSerializerFilter](https://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializerFilter.html) to not print the top node tags (not sure if that would work; I admit I've never used LSSerializer before.)

Reading the O'Reilly book seems to indicate doing something like this:

```
 DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
 DOMImplementationLS lsImpl = 
   (DOMImplementationLS)registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");
 LSSerializer serializer = lsImpl.createLSSerializer();
 String nodeString = serializer.writeToString(node);
```

Comment: No? .toString() of my td-Node would just result in "[b: null]"

Comment: Hmm, I guess I got that confused with Javascript + e4x. I meant call the function which just produces the output, then delete the beginning/end tags.

Answer (score 1):

What do you say about this ?
I had same problem today on android, but i managed to make simple "serializator"

```
private String innerXml(Node node){
        String s = "";
        NodeList childs = node.getChildNodes();
        for( int i = 0;i<childs.getLength();i++ ){
            s+= serializeNode(childs.item(i));
        }
        return s;
    }

    private String serializeNode(Node node){
        String s = "";
        if( node.getNodeName().equals("#text") ) return node.getTextContent();
        s+= "<" + node.getNodeName()+" ";
        NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
        if( attributes!= null ){
            for( int i = 0;i<attributes.getLength();i++ ){
                s+=attributes.item(i).getNodeName()+"=\""+attributes.item(i).getNodeValue()+"\"";
            }
        }
        NodeList childs = node.getChildNodes();
        if( childs == null || childs.getLength() == 0 ){
            s+= "/>";
            return s;
        }
        s+=">";
        for( int i = 0;i<childs.getLength();i++ )
            s+=serializeNode(childs.item(i));
        s+= "</"+node.getNodeName()+">";
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: I say 'thanks a lot'! You saved my time from doing the same thing. Considering performance it is probably the most effective way.

Answer (score 0):

node.getTextContent();

You ought to be using JDom of Dom4J to handle nodes, if for no other reasons, to handle whitespace correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To remove unneccesary tags probably such code can be used:

DOMConfiguration config = serializer.getDomConfig();
config.setParameter("canonical-form", true);

But it will not always work, because "canonical-form=true" is optional