# How order my xml file?

Tags: java, xml

I am serach alot of about how I can order my `xml` file. I create node `xml` by `java`, but file `xml` put my data in same line.

My output java :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Projects><ProjectDLocation><locationProject>Projects//arfqwre//ProjectDataBase.xml</locationProject><nameProject>arfqwre</nameProject></ProjectDLocation><ProjectDLocation><locationProject>Projects//arfqwre//ProjectDataBase.xml</locationProject><nameProject>arfqwre</nameProject></ProjectDLocation>
</Projects>
```

Just I need some way for order my node xml when I insert node:
For Example:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
        <Projects>
        <ProjectDLocation>
        <locationProject>Projects//arfqwre//ProjectDataBase.xml</locationProject>
    <nameProject>arfqwre</nameProject>
        </ProjectDLocation>
        <ProjectDLocation>
        <locationProject>Projects//arfqwre//ProjectDataBase.xml</locationProject>
<nameProject>arfqwre</nameProject>
        </ProjectDLocation>
        </Projects>
```

code java:

```
public void insertNewProjectLocation(Project entity) {

        String filePath = "DataBase//locationProject.xml";
        File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc;

            doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            Node projectData = doc.getElementsByTagName("Projects").item(0);

            Element ProjectDLocation = doc.createElement("ProjectDLocation");

            Element locationProject = doc.createElement("locationProject");
            if(entity.getLocation()==null){locationProject.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Projects" + "//" +entity.getName()+"//"+"ProjectDataBase.xml"));}
            else
            locationProject.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(entity.getLocation()));
            ProjectDLocation.appendChild(locationProject);

            Element nameProject = doc.createElement("nameProject");
            nameProject.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(entity.getName()));
            ProjectDLocation.appendChild(nameProject);
            projectData.insertBefore(ProjectDLocation, projectData.getFirstChild());
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File("DataBase//locationProject.xml"));
            transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            return;
        }

    }
```

Comment: It sounds like by "ordering" you're really talking about "formatting" - they're not the same thing. Also, you should show us your code.

Comment: what tool do you use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571866/java-xml-output-proper-indenting-for-child-items

Comment: but my code insert my data in same line in file xml , when my data is big i can't read my data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/139096/1311351

Comment: Search for "PrettyPrint". There are way too many answers on SO alone to list here!

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/139096/1311351 that what I need thanks so much