# Xml parsing for in between xml data with tags in java

Tags: java, xml

Xml parsing for inbetween xml data

I have a XML string in one my java String objects as below:

```
<Record>
    <op>Add</op>
    <sensdata>400188711111</sensdata>
    <id>4</id>
    <a1>1111201090467034</a1>
</Record>
```

If i need the data between

```
<Record> </Record>
```

i.e

```
<op>Add</op>
<sensdata>4001887XXXXX</sensdata>
<id>4</id>
<a1>1111201090467034</a1>
```

Can I get using the xml parser. I am able to get the values like Add40018871111141111201090467034. But not with tags.

Below is my code snippet

```
ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream("<Record><op>Add</op><sensdata>400188711111</sensdata><id>4</id><a1>1111201090467034</a1></Record>".getBytes());
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(stream);
NodeList sensdata = document.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("sensdata");
String sensitiveData = sensdata.item(0).getTextContent();
```

**Editing my question with the Solution i have tried:**

I did as below:

```
ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(toBeParsed.getBytes());
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(stream);      
NodeList XmlTagNodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName(XmlTag);
Document newXmlDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
        .newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
for (int i = 0; i < XmlTagNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = XmlTagNodeList.item(i);
    Node copyNode = newXmlDocument.importNode(node, true);
    newXmlDocument.appendChild(copyNode);
}

DOMImplementationLS domImplementationLS = (DOMImplementationLS) newXmlDocument.getImplementation();
LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplementationLS.createLSSerializer();
record = lsSerializer.writeToString(newXmlDocument);
System.out.println(record);
```

It prints record prepended with xml tag for every record.

Kindly let me know, is it a good way to do it? And I do not require xml tag. How to get rid of this?

Comment: Are you using dom4j ?

Comment: I am not sure of dom4j. I am using sax parser and org.w3c.dom package classes and methods

Comment: After i get the data in between <Record> </Record> like <op>Add</op><sensdata>400188711111</sensdata><id>4</id><a1>1111201090467034</a1> I need to feed this String (which is in xml format) to another api

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get full xml text from Node instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299752/get-full-xml-text-from-node-instance)

Comment: Yes this looks okay. But, this way its printing complete thing like     this <Record><op>Add</op> <sensdata>400188711111</sensdata><id>4</id> <a1>1111201090467034</a1></Record> Not the data in between <Record></Record>

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to output the XML literally, with the tags and stuff, you can do it by using the Transformer API available at javax.xml.transform.*

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no"); // I prefer to have the <?xml ?> tag
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); // Indent the code
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8"); // Original encoding
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4"); // Indent 4 spaces

// write the XML of a single node to an OutputStream
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node),  new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8")));
```

Is this what you need?

**Edit (looping through the nodes):**

```
// Your previous code
LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplementationLS.createLSSerializer();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
NodeList children = newXmlDocument.getChildNodes();
for(int x = 0; x < children.getLength(); x++)
{
    Node node = children.item(x);
    builder.append(lsSerializer.writeToString(node));
    builder.append("\n");
}
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Is that any help?

Comment: This works! But, this way its printing complete thing like this <Record><op>Add</op> <sensdata>400188711111</sensdata><id>4</id> <a1>1111201090467034</a1></Record> Not the data in between <Record></Record>. So do i have to convert nodelist to xmldoc?

Comment: Maybe you could transform each an every subnode of the <Record> node and append the results to a StringBuilder so it finally contains the inner XML data you need.  Remember then to switch off the xml declaration for each node so you don't have the <?xml ..?> directive over and over again

Comment: Kindly check my question. I have edited it with the solution i have tried.

Comment: Instead of passing the whole XML, if you want to get rid of the <Record>..</Record> parent node markups, access that node's children and loop through them, appending the results of the serialized nodes to a StringBuilder.  Something like: