# how can i get a response "AS IS" (format), in a string or in an inputstream?

Tags: java, xml, soap, response, inputstream

how can i get the response "AS IS" (XML Format) in a string or inputstream?
The response i am getting from my SOAP webservice in a String, it seems to be ALL in one line and not formatted XML. How can i do this? (Edited): I tried to change the getResponseBodyAsStream but i get this response: org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream@23597cac

Code to get the response:

```
String response = post.getResponseBodyAsString();

      bufferedReader.close();
      return response;
```

Returned string:

```
<tag1>name</tag1><name>JustaName</name>etc...
```

How can i get this nice like(example):

```
<tag1>name</tag1>
<name>JustaName
</name>etc...
```

Comment: this is how server sends response, you can't do anything, except it is your server :)

Comment: ok but in SoapUI i get the formatted response, maybe SoapUI has a formater?

Answer (score 0):

If you need that XML formatted badly, you can do it by building a Document out of it and then Transform it back to String.  Check [Get full xml text from Node instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299752/get-full-xml-text-from-node-instance)