# A library to produce canonical XML in JAVA 5?

Tags: java, xml, canonicalization

I'm using `org.apache.xml.security.c14n.Canonicalizer` which was recommended to me here: [Sort xml attributes for pretty print using javax.xml.transform.Transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9199739/323129). I will need it to run in Java 5 though.. it doesn't seem to work.

Are there any options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XOM](http://www.xom.nu/) has a [`Canonicalizer`](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/canonical/Canonicalizer.html) which will do this.

In addition to being a very good general-purpose XML DOM library, it's a much more lightweight solution to canonicalization than your XSLT-based solution.

Comment: I was my bad after all.. forgot the compiler on java7. All I had to do was build it right. Anyway, this is quite useful and also worked. thanks.