# Coldfusion wddx with indentation

Tags: coldfusion, wddx

I want to store my localization files in wddx format.

The problem is that sometimes I need to edit translation manually which might be a problem with wddx format as Coldfusion saves it in file as a single line.

Is there a way for me to format wddx string before saving it?

Leonti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think ColdFusion natively supports indenting xml/wddx. So either you can use [xmlindent from cflib.org](http://cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=2057) or if you are comfortable with java there are many solutions available [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264849/pretty-printing-output-from-javax-xml-transform-transformer-with-only-standard-j) like

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
// indent and omit xml declaration
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(source, result);
return result.getWriter().toString();
```