# carriage return or line break in a existing XML file

Tags: xml, cmd, ftp

We have some partners that send there product orders via an XML file. Wich they send to our server using FTP. A windows command line script will take it from the FTP server ans send it to our AS400/System I. Where it will be processed into a registered order.
Now are we starting to work with a new partner wich sends us XML in the same way a other partners the only problem is that this XML is made of 1 long line of code in stet of a pretty print lay out. This is a problem for the AS400 program.
I would like to ad some code in the Windows command line script to get a line break after each end tag
For example
Here is a part of the original XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><czavinh3 xmlns="urn:com.sap.b1i.vplatform:entity"><envelope><sender>Lottum</sender><receiver>8714253093123</receiver></envelope><message><docnum>1122259</docnum><docdtm>2015-09-28</docdtm><txts>test1234</txts>
```

Here is an example of what the as400 wants

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <czavinh3 xmlns="urn:com.sap.b1i.vplatform:entity">
    <envelope>
    <sender>Lottum</sender>
    <receiver>8714253093123</receiver>
    </envelope>
    <message>
    <docnum>1122259</docnum>
    <docdtm>2015-09-28</docdtm>
    <txts>test1234</txts>
```

I think the fastest way is to search and replace the >< for a >(enter)< this is easily done bye hand bud i have no idea how to automate this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not being a great programmer made my question a bit of a hard problem. Talking with some friends who have some more programming experience told me about FART (Find and Replace Text)

Download [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fart-it/files/).

This tool is an exe file witch allows you to change the ASCII from files.
My problem was that the incoming XML file is made out of 1 string this was a problem for processing it.

With the following statement I changed the XML to a Pretty Print file by entering a break line

```
    fart -c --c-style input.xml "><" ">\r<"
```

The option -c --c-style allows you to use c-cstyle extended characters like \r (Carriage Return)

Here are the other options u can use

```
    Find And Replace Text  v1.99b                         by Lionello Lunesu

    Usage: FART [options] [--] <wildcard>[,...] [find_string] [replace_string]

    Options:
    -h, --help          Show this help message (ignores other options)
    -q, --quiet         Suppress output to stdio / stderr
     -V, --verbose       Show more information
     -r, --recursive     Process sub-folders recursively
     -c, --count         Only show filenames, match counts and totals
     -i, --ignore-case   Case insensitive text comparison
     -v, --invert        Print lines NOT containing the find string
     -n, --line-number   Print line number before each line (1-based)
     -w, --word          Match whole word (uses C syntax, like grep)
     -f, --filename      Find (and replace) filename instead of contents
     -B, --binary        Also search (and replace) in binary files (CAUTION)
     -C, --c-style       Allow C-style extended characters (\xFF\0\t\n\r\\ etc.)
         --cvs           Skip cvs dirs; execute "cvs edit" before changing files
         --svn           Skip svn dirs
         --remove        Remove all occurences of the find_string
     -a, --adapt         Adapt the case of replace_string to found string
     -b, --backup        Make a backup of each changed file
     -p, --preview       Do not change the files but print the changes
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the posted document doesn't conform to xml standards. It's seem to be missing the closing tags `</message></czavinh3>`. Assuming they have been simply omitted and the xml is well-formed, you could use a small java program (following [Pretty-printing output from javax.xml.transform.Transformer with only standard java api (Indentation and Doctype positioning)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264849/pretty-printing-output-from-javax-xml-transform-transformer-with-only-standard-j)) like:

```
package xmlprettyprint;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class XmlPrettyPrint {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException, FileNotFoundException {

        // Instantiate transformer input
        Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new FileReader(args[0]));
        StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());

        // Configure transformer
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
            .newTransformer(); // An identity transformer
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "testing.dtd");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);

        System.out.println(xmlOutput.getWriter().toString());
    }
}
```

It reads the filename from the commandline, parses it and does a pretty-print output, resulting in output like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE czavinh3 SYSTEM "testing.dtd">
    <czavinh3 xmlns="urn:com.sap.b1i.vplatform:entity">
    <envelope>
    <sender>Lottum</sender>
    <receiver>8714253093123</receiver>
    </envelope>
    <message>
    <docnum>1122259</docnum>
    <docdtm>2015-09-28</docdtm>
    <txts>test1234</txts>
    </message>
    </czavinh3>
```

Provided the jar file would be named xmlPrettyPrint.jar, you can call the java program from command line like:

```
java -jar xmlPrettyPrint.jar input.xml
```

and output would be like above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help I'm trying to test the code you made but I get an error


        C:\batch\CarriageReturn>java -jar xmlPrettyPrint Agrocultuur.xml
        Error: Unable to access jarfile xmlPrettyPrint

Comment: You have to compile the given java code into a jar file. Or directly compile it into a class file.

Comment: I have compiled the code and when I run the file is get another error big change it is something small bud i have no knowledge of java what so ever this is the error I'm getting Error: Could not find or load main class XmlPrettyPrint

Comment: Thanks for your help but I found an other way to solve my problem