# Formatting XML for display in a TextView?

Tags: android

Is there a tool/library/class/function for formatting XML when displaying it in a TextView in Android? I need to present some XML snippets to users and was looking for a convenient way to achieve this, rather than having to parse and format it manually...

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pretty print XML from Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post will help you

[How to pretty print XML from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java)