# Is there Swing component that will automatically format XML?

Tags: java, xml, swing

I am looking for Java Swing component, that will automatically format my messy XML (in one line, see example):

```
<person><name>Joe</name><surname>Black</surname></person>
```

etc. etc.

Its not very nice to see like billion lines long line :) And I hope there is some component, that'll do the dirty work for me. Thankx

**Edit:**
I get XML input as plain string from database, so there is no real XML doc for me :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to rely on a Swing component to do the formatting. You can try pretty printing your XML and set the formatted output directly in your component. This has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java).

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use a Java-based DOM. We use [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/) (in which case use serializer()) to get the format that you require in a text string, and then repaint your component.

Also see examples in: [How to pretty print XML from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java)

Parse the string into the DOM. For example:

```
Document doc = new Builder().build(new StringReader(yourXML));
```

to get the outputStream use

```
os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

then use the serializer to produce text:

```
Serializer serializer = new Serializer(os);
serializer.setTheFormatYouWant(... several options in the class ...);
serializer.output(doc);
```

and then

```
os.toString();
```