# Formatting XML data using Java

Tags: java, xml

I have some XML data:

```
<entries><entry><templateID>F04FD51B-C537-4d02-BB1D-E89971D1D65</templateID><entryID>41</entryID><subject>Updated Terms and Conditions</subject>
```

I want to format the XMl data into proper format using Java code

Can any one suggest, how to format XML data using Java.

Comment: What do you mean "format"? It might help if you showed us a snippet of the file now, and a snippet of how you want it to look.

Comment: That doesn't look like XML data to me.  I suggest you work out how to make it look like valid XML data in an editor first before you try to program it.

Comment: @Peter - I'm not seeing a link or data?

Comment: Ahh - I though F04FD... was the file name! OK yes, this is not xml.

Comment: @Richard, I am ssuming the `data(...)` contains the information he wants to format as XML.  But until he knows what it would look like he won't be able to program it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pretty print xml from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java)

Answer (score 1):

See [how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java)