# Sort an XML subtree in Java

Tags: java, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to canonicalize WSDL files in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446904/how-to-canonicalize-wsdl-files-in-java)

I need to reorder some XML nodes using Java. Actually, I need [to canonicalize a WSDL file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446904/how-to-canonicalize-wsdl-files-in-java), but some hand-made reordering should do as well.

I know, I can use `org.w3c.dom.Document` and iterate through all its children, etc., but it's quite tedious (the `NodeList` is not even `Iterable`) and I wonder if there's something usable.

Comment: I would suggest you first checkout my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446904/how-to-canonicalize-wsdl-files-in-java

Comment: Maybe you should iterate and create a new Document.

Comment: **Obviously, this is no duplicate, just a related question.** This question was about the sorting, the other was about how the canonical form of WSDL looks like (and if there's a tool doing it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it with [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/). A dom4j [`Element`](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Element.html) provides a [live List view of its sub-elements](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Element.html#elements%28%29), which you can sort. And with a [`Visitor`](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Visitor.html) you can modify an entire document:

```
Document document = DocumentHelper.parseText(someXml);
final Comparator<Element> comparator = new Comparator<Element>() {
    public int compare(Element o1, Element o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
};
Visitor visitor = new VisitorSupport() {
    @Override
    public void visit(Element node) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // dom4j doesn't know generics yet
        List<Element> elements = node.elements();
        Collections.sort(elements, comparator);
        super.visit(node);
    }
};
document.accept(visitor);
// now write the document back to a file
```

It doesn't get much easier than this.

---

**Update:** After trying to use my own solution much later, I realized that it doesn't work that way. The list returned by `Element.elements()` doesn't like `Collections.sort()`, so you will have to use the List returned by `Element.content()`. Unfortunately this means that your comparator will have to deal with `Node`, rather than `Element`, which will get very messy if you have mixed content.

Comment: This looks nice, just the comparator needs to access the attribute "name" instead of the element's name.

Comment: If the sort criteria can be expressed as an XPath on each of the list item, dom4j's `XPath` class has a `sort(List list)` method that can do the job. e.g. `new DefaultXPath("./book/title/text()").sort(library.content());` (you may need to set the namespaces on the XPath before calling this method)

Comment: This answer is correct, just like you had mentioned in update, only works with `element.content()`. Please update the code to reflect the same. Though I understand its a very old answer.

Answer (score 2):

You've made the first step, which is to recognize that doing this kind of job in Java with DOM-like interfaces is tedious in the extreme. Now take the next step - it's much easier in XSLT.