# Having Element.toXML() properly indented instead of showing the resulting string just as a single line?

Tags: java, xml, xom

The default behavior of `Element.toXML()` seems to be showing up the result as a single line. Is it possible to have it show the result in multiple lines, in a hierarchical way?

Example:

This is what I'd like to get

```
<root>
    <Fraction hash="108e898f" />
    <Integer hash="19498483" />
</root>
```

and this is what I'm getting at the moment:

```
<root><Fraction hash="108e898f" /><Integer hash="19498483" /></root>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`nu.xom.Serializer`](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/Serializer.html) is exactly what you need. Here's a usage [example](http://www.xom.nu/tutorial.xhtml#d0e155):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Element root = new Element("root");  
    Element fraction = new Element("Fraction");
    fraction.addAttribute(new Attribute("hash", "108e898f"));
    root.appendChild(fraction);
    Element integer = new Element("Integer");
    integer.addAttribute(new Attribute("hash", "19498483"));
    root.appendChild(integer);
    Document doc = new Document(root);
    try {
        Serializer serializer = new Serializer(System.out, "ISO-8859-1");
        serializer.setIndent(4);
        serializer.setMaxLength(64);
        serializer.write(doc);  
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex); 
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want a pretty print output. Doing that with Xom should be easy, try [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/962225/633239), it may be helpful.