# Displaying xml in jsp

Tags: xml, jsp

I am trying to show a string containing xml data in xml format, on a jsp page.
I do not want to parse the xml but just want to show on the browser xml data.

Would someone be able to help me out with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 <pre>
   <c:out value="${xmlString}" />
 </pre>
```

This will pretty print the xml

Comment: In my case it just prints only XML tag values. It doe not print tags. Why so ? Any more setting needed ?

Comment: I realized that <c:out> is not being recognized. So I added <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> After adding it (and adding supporting jar jstl-1.2.jar) it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
<c:out value="${theXmlString}"/>
```

If you want to preserve line breaks, use a pre tag:

```
<pre><c:out value="${theXmlString}"/></pre>
```

Comment: thank you.. but it does not seem to print out the xml in xml format.. it just prints it out as one single string..

Comment: It prints it as it is in the XML string. Do you mean you would like to indent the XML string? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java