# Display XML in jsp file using Spring MVC

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to display an XML file in jsp. The code should go to a particular location and read xml and then show it in a jsp.

I have done the file reading part but when I try to show that in jsp I am getting error. I tried different ways, like escaping char, setting content type, but every time I get a different error.

One of them is -

> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location:
>
> http://localhost:8080/viewXmlFile
>
> Line Number 8, Column 12:

Is there any way I can show the XML file in jsp? I am using Spring MVC.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewXmlFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewXmlFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String path = //sec15/folder/myXmlFile.xml;

    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
    try(BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);) {
        List<String> collect = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (String line : collect) {
            data.append(line + CommonConstants.FILE_NEXT_LINE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("viewXmlFile");
    model.addObject("xmlData", data.toString());
    return model;
}
```

This is the JSP file-

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<body>
<pre>
    <c:out value="${xmlData}" />
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the XML, I am trying to show-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns14:Appearance xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/ObjectMetadata/9.0" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/TransactionMetadata/9.0" xmlns:ns14="http://www.example.com/Appearance/2.56">
    <ns3:TransactionMetadata>
        <SourceSystem>Alpha</SourceSystem>
        <TransactionType>Appearance</TransactionType>
        <UniqueTransactionId>8d797d156487</UniqueTransactionId>
        <TransactionDateTime>2017-05-23T03:04:48.025+02:00</TransactionDateTime>
    </ns3:TransactionMetadata>
    <Appearance>
        <ns2:ObjectMetadata>
            <ActionType>Update</ActionType>
            <BusinessObjectName>Appearance</BusinessObjectName>
        </ns2:ObjectMetadata>
        <AppearanceUID>A500003410</AppearanceUID>
        <AppearanceNumber>001</AppearanceNumber>
        <AppearanceName>1495501</AppearanceName>
        <CreationDate>2017-05-23T03:04:37+02:00</CreationDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2017-05-23T03:04:38+02:00</ModifiedDate>
    </Appearance>
</ns14:Appearance>
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419044/displaying-xml-in-jsp

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Edit your question and offer java code and `JSP`.

Comment: @RubioRic I tried that too. "<?xml v" This is what I got at the jsp file.

Comment: As @beckyang has suggested, post an example: what is your xml, your code to read it, the controller, the view (jsp page), ... There's no need to post all your code, just the relevant parts related to this problem.

Comment: @RubioRic I have added the code also.

Comment: @beckyang I have added the code.

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo but you got a blank space in `<@ taglib`. It should be `<@tablib`

Comment: @RubioRic it doesn't matter. we can have space. anyhow i tried with '<@taglib' also, but the result remained the same.

Comment: I cannot get the error message using web browser. But I find a mistake in your XML, `</ns14:AppearanceTransaction>` should be `</ns14:Appearance>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing the jsp file I am able to view the XML on jsp.

This is the code I have in jsp now-

```
<%@page contentType="text/xml" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>${xmlData}
```