# Java - convert pipe delimited text\csv file to XML

Tags: java, xml

I'm wondering if there is an accepted method to convert a Pipe delimited text file to XML in Java. The delimited file I am looking to convert is in the format:

```
RefNo   |    Location   |   Name  |  Age
123     | North America |  Steve  |  32
```

And I am looking to convert it to:

```
<data>
    <RefNo>123</RefNo> 
    <location>North America</location>
    <name> Steve </name>
    <age> 32 </age>
</data>
```

Comment: Is this a one-off, or do you have a whole bunch of files with different headings?

Comment: Also, what rule maps `RefNo` to `RefNo` but `Name` to `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some answers to your question, but first you should replace the pipe separator by a comma, because it is `CSV` to `XML`.

You can do it using `s.replaceAll("|",",")` in `String` class and following these instructions:

[Conversion of CSV to XML with JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120055/conversion-of-csv-to-xml-with-java)

[Java lib or app to convert CSV to XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123/converting-csv-file-to-xml-in-java)

Comment: It's worth observing that any decent CSV library (and all of the ones mentioned in your second link) will be able to handle pipe-delimited files as well as CSV. Your suggested conversion is potentially dangerous if there is some sort of quote character in the pipe-delimited file.

Answer (score 1):

Run the XSLT transformation given here, or adapt it as needed:

http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/csv/csv-to-xml_v2.html

Answer (score 0):

I Found 1 more way to convert CSV TO XML....

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
public class CSV2XML {
// Protected Properties
    protected DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = null;
    protected DocumentBuilder domBuilder = null;
// CTOR
    public CSV2XML()
    {
        try
        {
            domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        }
        catch(FactoryConfigurationError exp)
        {
            System.err.println(exp.toString());
        }
        catch(ParserConfigurationException exp)
        {
            System.err.println(exp.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            System.err.println(exp.toString());
        }
    }
    public int convertFile(String csvFileName, String xmlFileName)
    {
        int rowsCount = -1;
        try
        {
            Document newDoc = domBuilder.newDocument();
// Root element
            Element rootElement = newDoc.createElement("CSV2XML");
            newDoc.appendChild(rootElement);

// Read comma seperated file

            BufferedReader csvReader;
            csvFileName = "C:\\frnds.csv";
            csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileName));
            int fieldCount = 0;
            String[] csvFields = null;
            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = null;
// Assumption: first line in CSV file is column/field  names
// As the column names are used to name the elements in the XML file,
// avoid using spaces/any other characters not suitable   for XML element naming

            String curLine = csvReader.readLine();
            if(curLine != null)
            {
                stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(curLine, ",");
                fieldCount = stringTokenizer.countTokens();
                if(fieldCount > 0)
                {
                    csvFields = new String[fieldCount];
                    int i=0;
                    while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements())
                        csvFields[i++] =
                                String.valueOf(stringTokenizer.nextElement());
                }
            }
// Now we know the columns, Let's now read data row lines
            while((curLine = csvReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(curLine, ",");
                fieldCount = stringTokenizer.countTokens();
                if(fieldCount > 0)
                {
                    Element rowElement = newDoc.createElement("row");
                    int i=0;
                    while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            String curValue =
                                    String.valueOf(stringTokenizer.nextElement());
                            Element curElement =
                                    newDoc.createElement(csvFields[i++]);
                            curElement.appendChild(newDoc.createTextNode(curValue));
                            rowElement.appendChild(curElement);
                        }
                        catch(Exception exp)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                    rootElement.appendChild(rowElement);
                    rowsCount++;
                }
            }
            csvReader.close();
// Save the document to the disk file
            TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();
            Source src = new DOMSource(newDoc);
            xmlFileName = "C:\\stest.xml";
            Result dest = new StreamResult(new File(xmlFileName));
            aTransformer.transform(src, dest);
            rowsCount++;
        }
        catch(IOException exp)
        {
            System.err.println(exp.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            System.err.println(exp.toString());
        }
        return rowsCount;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            args = new String[] {"C:\\frnds.csv", "C:\\stest.xml"};
            if(args.length != 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Usage: java CSV2XML <inputCSVFile> <outputXMLFile>");
                return;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            System.err.println(exp.toString());
        }
        try
        {
            CSV2XML csvConverter = new CSV2XML();
            int rowsCount = csvConverter.convertFile(args[0], args[1]);
            if(rowsCount >= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("CSV File '" + args[0] + "' successfully converted to XML File '"+ args[1] + "'\n" + "(" + String.valueOf(rowsCount) + " rows)");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error while converting input CSV  File '" + args[0] + "' to output XML File '"+ args[1] + "'");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            System.err.println(exp.toString());
        }
    }
}
```