# Converting CSV File to Hierarchy XML in JAVA with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, csv, jaxb

I need to create a Hierarchical XML using CSV file.

```
id,firstname,Lastname
1,yong,mook kim
2, Alez, Aunritod
,...
```

I tried to do it with JAXB and create the classes manually

```
public class WriteXMLFile {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

      try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // root elements
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        // staff elements
        Element staff = doc.createElement("Staff");
        rootElement.appendChild(staff);

        // set attribute to staff element
        Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
        attr.setValue("1");
        staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

        Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
        firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("yong"));
        staff.appendChild(firstname);

        // lastname elements
        Element lastname = doc.createElement("lastname");
        lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mook kim"));
        staff.appendChild(lastname);
```

But my issue is that I want to read the Value of each node from my csv file not manually in the code

```
        Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
        firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("yong"));
        staff.appendChild(firstname);
```

Can anyone help me how can I read it from my sample.csv file instead of manually?

Comment: You can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120055/conversion-of-csv-to-xml-with-java

Comment: I have seen the mentioned link and I tried it but did not give me the result

Comment: The mentioned link is about pretty printing, but my issue is not pretty printing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with following solution,

firstly read the csv file and collect the objects (person) from individual lines. then marshal the list of objects to xml file

People.java (root element of xml file)

```
@XmlRootElement(name="people")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class People {

    @XmlElement(name="person")
    private List<Person> listPerson;

    public List<Person> getListPerson() {
        return listPerson;
    }
    public void setListPerson(List<Person> listPerson) {
        this.listPerson = listPerson;
    }
}
```

Person.java (child elements of parent (people) element)

```
@XmlRootElement(name="person")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

marshaling with java

```
public class Marshaller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br;
        String line;
        People people = new People();
        ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList();

        //read the csv file and collect the person objects
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inputCSV.csv"));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {    //get every single line individually in csv file
                String[] value = line.split(",");   //collect the comma separated values into array
                Person person = new Person();
                person.setId(value[0]); //first element of an array is id
                person.setFirstName(value[1]);  //second element of an array is firstName
                person.setLastName(value[2]);   //third element of an array is lastName
                list.add(person);   //add person object into the list
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        people.setListPerson(list); //set person object list to people
        people.getListPerson().remove(0);   //remove the first person object of list. because it holds the column's names

        //marshaling with java
        try {

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(People.class);
            javax.xml.bind.Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(people, new File("output.xml"));
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(people, System.out);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

inputCSV.csv

```
id,firstname,Lastname
1,yong,mook kim
2, Alez, Aunritod
```

output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<people>
    <person>
        <id>1</id>
        <firstName>yong</firstName>
        <lastName>mook kim</lastName>
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>2</id>
        <firstName> Alez</firstName>
        <lastName> Aunritod</lastName>
    </person>
</people>
```

Comment: If I have some other class, inside person, with name PersonDetail, and this class has other three elements, how can I do it? Can you help me about this?

Comment: if you want to add `<persondetail>` tag as a child tag of `<person>` tag and above three elements (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`) are included under the `<persondetail>` tag. like that, `<person><persondetail>
        <id>2</id>
        <firstName> Alez</firstName>
        <lastName> Aunritod</lastName>
    </persondetail></person>`