# java xml document.getTextContent() stays empty

Tags: java, xml, xmldom

I'm trying to build an xml document in a JUnit test.

```
doc=docBuilder.newDocument();   
Element root = doc.createElement("Settings");
doc.appendChild(root);          
Element label0 = doc.createElement("label_0");
root.appendChild(label0);
String s=doc.getTextContent();
System.out.println(s);
```

Yet the document stays empty (i.e. the `println` yields `null`.)  I don'thave a clue why that is.  The actual problem is that a subsequent XPath expression throws the error: `Unable to evaluate expression using this context`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `getTextContent` on `Document` is defined to null- See [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29).

To retreive the text contents call getTextNode on the root element

Comment: Long liveth the 'principle of the least surprise'!

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you want to serialize the document to pass it to the test case.
To do this you have to pass your document to an empty XSL transformer, like this:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
//initialize StreamResult with File object to save to file
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(source, result);
String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
System.out.println(xmlString);
```

See also: [How to pretty print XML from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java)

Comment: Though this is a nice-to-have, I was rather concerned that my document was empty.  Thanks anyway.