# Unescaping HTML without touching XML characters

Tags: java, html, xml

I have an XML file containing escaped HTML characters and escaped XML characters as seen here:

```
<question description="How can I unescape only HTML characters such as: &Atilde; and &#48;,but not special characters such as &amp;">
```

How can I unescape all HTML characters and leave the below XML characters unescaped:

```
- &amp;
- &gt;
-&lt;
-&quot;
-&apos;
```

When I used `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml()` it also escaped the XML characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unescape HTML entities but leave XML entities untouched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347441/how-to-unescape-html-entities-but-leave-xml-entities-untouched)

Answer (score 0):

From [@Roman post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59767771/14048240)

Create a class and name it `HtmlEscapeUtils`:

```
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.AggregateTranslator;
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.CharSequenceTranslator;
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.EntityArrays;
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.LookupTranslator;
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.NumericEntityUnescaper;


public class HtmlEscapeUtils {

  /**
   * @see {@link org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils#UNESCAPE_HTML4}
   */
  public static final CharSequenceTranslator UNESCAPE_HTML_SPECIFIC =
      new AggregateTranslator(
          new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.ISO8859_1_UNESCAPE),
          new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.HTML40_EXTENDED_UNESCAPE),
          new NumericEntityUnescaper());


  /**
   * @see {@link org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils#unescapeHtml4(String)}
   * @param input - HTML String with e.g. &quot; &amp; &auml;
   * @return XML String, HTML4 Entities replaced, but XML Entites remain (e.g. &quot; und &amp;)
   */
  public static final String unescapeHtmlToXml(final String input) {
    return UNESCAPE_HTML_SPECIFIC.translate(input);
  }

}
```

And use it in your program

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String source = "How can I unescape only HTML characters such as: &Atilde; and &#48;,but not special characters such as &amp; or &gt;";
        String escaped = HtmlEscapeUtils.unescapeHtmlToXml(source);
        System.out.println(escaped);
    }
```

You need the following dependency in your program

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
  <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```