# Since moving to java 1.7 Xml Document Element does not indent

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, transform

I'm trying to indent XML which generated by Transformer.
All the DOM Node are being Indent as expected except for the First Node - The Document Element.
document element does not start in a new line , just concat right after the XML Declaration.

This bug arise when I moved to java 1.7 , when using java 1.6 or 1.5 it does not happen.

My code :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream s = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "utf-8");

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount","4");

transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(s));
```

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a>
       <b>bbbbb</b>
 </a>
```

Anyone knows why ?

btw,
when I add the property

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
```

It work as expected , but the xml declaration is changed,
it now have the standalone property as well, and i don't want to change the xml declaration..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok ,

I found in Java API this :

If the doctype-system property is specified, the xml output method should output a document type declaration immediately before the first element.

SO I used this property

```
 transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, "yes");
```

and it solve my problem with out changed my xml declartion.

Thanks.

Comment: Was looking for this couple of days :)

Comment: This does not work for me. Setting only DOCTYPE_PUBLIC=yes does not make the document element start on a new line. Only STANDALONE=yes or no does the thing, but I do not want to explicitly specify it, because I do not use a DTD, I use schema.

Answer (score 3):

Xalan has at some point changed the behavior regarding the newline character after the XML declaration.

OpenJDK (and thus Oracle JDK, too) has implemented a [workaround](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7150637) for this problem. This workaround can be enabled by setting a special property on the `Transformer` object:

```
try {
    transformer.setOutputProperty("http://www.oracle.com/xml/is-standalone", "yes");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // Might be thrown by JDK versions not implementing the workaround.
}
```

This way, the old behavior (printing a newline character after the XML declaration) is restored without adding the standalone attribute to the XML declaration.

Answer (score 1):

For me writing the XML declaration to the `Writer` or `OutputStream` before writing the XML and telling the transformer to omit declaration was the only thing that worked. The only other solution to preserve the spacing appears to be VTD-XML library.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<?xml version=\"").append(doc.getXmlVersion()).append("\"");
    sb.append(" encoding=\"").append(doc.getXmlEncoding()).append("\"");
    if (doc.getXmlStandalone()) {
        sb.append(" standalone=\"").append("" + doc.getXmlStandalone()).append("\"");
    }
    sb.append("?>").append("\n");

    writer.write(sb.toString());
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    }
    catch (Exception e)  {
    //snipped out for brevity
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem (bug) of the XML implementaion in Java. The only way to get a linebreak after the XML declaration is to explicitly specify the `standalone` attribute. You may set it to `no`, which is the implicit default, even if it is completely irrelevant when not using a DTD.