# Autoformat HTML-Strings in Java

Tags: java, formatting, string-formatting

I am autogenerating HTML-Strings in Java. Unfortunately in the output everything appears in a long row. It's too much effort to put \n or \t before the Output-String due to sometimes I'm containing several objects in each other (Like Divs and Tables).

Are there some frameworks available which support HTML-Autoformat in Java?
Thanks

Comment: Oh the irony in *too much effort*...

Comment: Imagine there are several tables within a table which might contain a DIV-Element which contains stuff as well. This stuff itself is complex enough, I'm not keen on thinking about how much Tabs I need in front of every row...

Comment: The irony in *too much effort* was that you seemingly didn't even bother searching before asking a question that has been answered before. Of course, I don't know for a fact that you didn't search. There is a reasonable chance that you did search, and didn't find the answer suggested below. That's why I made the comment in jest, and meant no offense.

Comment: As said to Daniel down there I was focused too much on how to format HTML, I haven't even thought of XML...

Comment: Well, HTML is basically a form of XML, though some would argue that only applies to XHTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this answer for pretty printing of XML (it should also work for HTML): [How to pretty print XML from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java)

Comment: Thank you!
Obviously I haven't seen the wood for the trees. Of course a XML-Formatter does exactly that - I was focused too much on the HTML...