# Serialized XML to String

Tags: java, xml, serialization

I generate a XML like this. It works fine. But I want to print it out in Eliscps:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

public class PersonConstructor {
    String info="";
    String path="c://myfile/myperson";

    // here is my xml object
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setFirstName("fname");
    person.setLastName("lname");
    person.setTel("111-111-1111");
    person.setAddress("1000 main st.");

    //Serializer my object to file.
    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    File file = new File(path);
    serializer.write(person, file);

    //now I want to print out my xml file.I don't know how to do it.
    info = file.toString();
    System.out.println(info);
}
```

Should I use output stream?

Comment: the serializer.write has an overload that accepts an outputStream. You could construct a ByteArrayOutputStream, have the serializer write to it, then construct a new string from the bytes like new String(myBAOS.getBytes());  then just print it. That will avoid disk IO entirely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pretty print XML from Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java)

Comment: the code is:   ' Serializer serializer = new Persister(); 
  OutputStream os =new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  serializer.write(person,os);
  info=os.toString();'
  return msg;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a buffered reader. Just make sure to either add the IOException to your method signature or surround with try/catch block.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = in.readLine();
while(line != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
    line = in.readLine();
}
in.close();
```