# StringTemplate indentation adds whitespace inside String

Tags: java, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

This is obviously a SSCCE.

I have the following template file:

```
xml(value)::=<<
<a>
    <b>
        ^value^
    </b>
</a>
>>
```

... with the following code:

```
private static final String VALUE="alpha\nbeta";
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    STGroup stGroup = new STGroupFile("templates/a.xml.stg", '^', '^');
    ST st = stGroup.getInstanceOf("xml");
    st.add("value", VALUE);
    System.out.printf("--------\n%s\n--------", st.render());
}
```

The code produces:

```
 [java] --------
 [java] <a>
 [java]     <b>
 [java]         alpha
 [java]         beta
 [java]     </b>
 [java] </a>
 [java] --------
```

In other words, the String value is modified as whitespace is added. When a client parses the XML file, even with whitespace trimming, the String value will be perceived as changed as whitespace has been added **inside** the String.

I understand that a solution is to declare the template as:

```
xml(value)::=<<
<a>
    <b>^value^</b>
</a>
>>
```

... but even this solution necessitates that all other nodes which may contain the `xml` rendering are also right-justified.

E.g., assuming that the above rendered value is embedded in another template, then the following template:

```
enclosing-document(xml)::=<<
<h1>
    <h2>
        ^xml^
    </h2>
</h1>
>>
```

... will also have to be re-written as:

```
enclosing-document(xml)::=<<
<h1>
    <h2>
^xml^
    </h2>
</h1>
>>
```

... in effect necessitating the left-justification of all nodes to be sure.

Is there a way to instruct StringTemplate to just emit a particular String parameter as it is (without indenting it in case of new lines present within) while at the same time preserve whitespace / indentation for all other cases (so that my rendered output will not be ugly)?

## Update

I tried using the [NoIndentWriter](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/index.html?org/stringtemplate/v4/NoIndentWriter.html) but was met [with other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27931007/274677). So it appears that the `NoIndentWriter` does indeed emit the multiline String as it is but does **not** honor whitespace present in the template file. So I am back at square one.

Comment: Would enclosing the content in `<![CDATA[]]>` section change the result?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am not sure I understand what you propose. At any rate, if CDATA is added in the template, then nothing changes in respect to the insertion of whitespace during the indentation of the multi-line String. Further, I am not sure adding a CDATA section in my final document is free from side-effects.

Comment: I was thinking about `<b><![CDATA[^value^]]></b>`, hoping that stringtemplate would pay attention to `CDATA` sections. It looks like it doesn't. Oh well...

Comment: Maybe try a different templating engine?  FreeMarker? Velocity?   Or since you're generating XML, why not use an XML generation library?  Xerces, XStream, Smooks, etc.

Comment: @MikeClark I 'd like to upvote the code you previously added and accept it as a solution as it's the best that can be done given the limitations (even though it does lose all indentation).

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus [Your approach to using NoIndentWriter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27931007/274677) is much more elegant than my code, since your approach does not require complicated subclassing.  I think we achieve the same effect but you use far less code.  I suggest you answer your own question with that code and accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

So in the end what I did was to use the [NoIndentWriter](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/index.html?org/stringtemplate/v4/NoIndentWriter.html) with the code given [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27931007/274677). Then, to solve the lack of indentation that results in ugly XML (complained about in the aforementioned post), I used the XML pretty-printer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11519668/274677).