# Xerces2 XML parser and Xalan XSLT processor -- state and replacement?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan, xerces2-j

It is year 2018. What is the state of the [Xerces2 XML parser](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/) and [Xalan XSLT processor](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/index.html) libraries for Java? Their last releases appear to be [2.11.0 in 2013](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl) and [2.7.2 in 2014](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/xalan) respectively.

- Are they still maintained?
- Are they so perfect that they do not need even occasional patch release?
- Are there replacement libraries from different vendors that one could use instead? Are these replacements free in the same way as these two?
- Can one generally do without these with just what JDK offers?

Comment: I prefer Saxon as XSLT processor.

Comment: Saxon 9.8 HE is an XSLT 3.0 processor available as open-source on SourceForge https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/latest/download?source=files and on Maven so it can be considered a replacement for Xalan as Xalan implements XSLT and XPath 1.0 from 1999 while Saxon 9.8 supports the latest XSLT 3.0  and XPath 3.1 from 2017.

Answer (score 5):

Active development of Xerces and Xalan stopped much earlier than these last releases. In between there were plenty of patch releases to fix bugs. It's quite natural that after a few years of issuing bug fixes only, with no new development, software becomes very stable and no further maintenance releases are required.

For many years I used to advise using the Apache version of Xerces because it was more reliable than the version in the JDK: the JDK version had some nasty bugs and Sun/Oracle seemed in no hurry to fix them. I think that has now changed; the JDK versions are now perfectly usable.

If you need XSLT features beyond the 1.0 level, then switch from Xalan to Saxon.

Comment: With all due respect, please disclose your affiliation.

Comment: JDK version has [limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347767/prevent-wrapping-of-lines-when-pretty-printing-xml-string) essential and very useful library functionality

Answer (score 1):

Basically these are jaxp implementations that were donated to Apache by different companies. Crimson is another one that was donated by SUN. These days a jaxp implementation is bundled with the JDK so there is very little reason to use an alternative implementation. As I recall from way back, you'd typically pull in xerces or xalan as a dependency when doing j2ee applications before that was the case.

[check the unoffical jaxp faq](https://people.apache.org/~edwingo/jaxp-faq.html)