# How do I return a subsection of an XML request based on an XPath expression

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have written code that enables me to a subsection of an xml request based on a given XPath, however, it is only the value between the tags that are returned and not the tags.

I want both values and elements to be returned based on a given xpath.

For example, in this xml:

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
  <staff1>
    <name>john</name>
    <phone>465456433</phone>
    <email>gmail1</email>
    <area>area1</area>
    <city>city1</city>
  </staff1>
  <staff2>
    <name>mary</name>
    <phone>4655556433</phone>
    <email>gmail2</email>
    <area>area2</area>
    <city>city2</city>
  </staff2>
  <staff3>
    <name>furvi</name>
    <phone>4655433</phone>
    <email>gmail3</email>
    <area>area3</area>
    <city>city3</city>
  </staff3>
</company>
```

my XPath would only return the value of the first staff element i.e.

```
John
465456433
gmail1
area1
city1
```

It does not return the tags associated to it i.e, it should return the following:

```
<staff1>
    <name>john</name>
    <phone>465456433</phone>
    <email>gmail1</email>
    <area>area1</area>
    <city>city1</city>
  </staff1>
```

Here is my code:

```
      InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            String RecordCategory;

        Document doc = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputSource);

        // Create XPathFactory object
        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

        // Create XPath object
        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

        System.out.println("TESTING XPATH");

        xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
            @Override
            public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
...
               });
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//staff1[1]");




        Staff1 = (String) expr.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println("staff1: " + staff1);
```

Anyone have any idea on what I could do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your Java call to `XPathExpression.evaluation()` is returning the ***string value*** of the node selected by your XPath expression.  If you instead want to return the ***node*** selected by your XPath expression, change

```
Staff1 = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

to

```
Node node = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11519668/290085) for how to pretty print `node`.