# Is it possible to specify the behavior of EOL when using XMLOutputFactory?

Tags: java, scala, xmlstreamwriter

I like to write an xml Elem to a file, but I want to set the line separator between each node of the elem, so when opening the file under windows or ubuntu I have the correct format. for example :

```
val lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator") 
val xmlData : Elem = <person>
       <firstName>John</firstName>
       <lastName>Doe</lastName>
  <emails>
  <email type=”primary”>john.doe@noone.com</email>
  <email type=”secondary”>john.doe@noone.com</email>
  </emails>
  <address>
  <street>595 Market Street</street>
  <city>San Francisco</city>
  <zip>94105</zip>
  </address>
  </person>

val xmlStreamWriter = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance.createXMLStreamWriter(outputstream)
xmlStreamWriter.writeDTD(xmlData)
```

How to write it into a file considering the lineSeparator?
the **XMLOutputFactory** have the method  **setProperty()** is it possible to specify the line separator here?

Comment: *FYI:* [`writeDTD()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html#writeDTD-java.lang.String-) is for writing a [`doctypedecl`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-doctypedecl), i.e. a `<!DOCTYPE ... >`, not the entire XML document.

Comment: If `Elem` is a DOM node, don't use `XMLStreamWriter` for creating XML text. See [How to pretty print XML from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/139076/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

From [The standard Scala XML library - Getting started](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/wiki/Getting-started) guide:

> To write XML to a file:
>
> ```scala
> scala.xml.XML.save("books.xml", books)
> ```
>
> To format XML use the `scala.xml.PrettyPrinter` to configure the line length and indentation level:
>
> ```scala
> val pp = new scala.xml.PrettyPrinter(24, 4)
> pp.format(books)
> ```

Comment: I do not want to use XLM.save  methode because  I want to stream the XML content, and the **PrettyPrinter** will format all xml content, I do not want to format the text inside XML node. for example : 
`<text> {hello "\n" world} <\text>`  with the PrettyPrinter  will be outputed like this 
`<text> hello  world <\text>` the "\n" will be removed

Comment: In addition to that the PrettyPrinter use internally "\n" as EOL for XML tags.