# How to fix the xml file indentation before prompt user for download?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot Java to prompt user to save an XML file.

My code is the following:

```
public class ExportE125Controller  {
 
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcExportE125")
    private JdbcTemplate template;    
    
    @RequestMapping(path = "/exportE125",  method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes ="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getE125New(@RequestParam Map<String, String> body,HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String str = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>"
                
        byte[] output =str.getBytes("UTF-8");
        
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set("charset", "utf-8");
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/xml"));
        responseHeaders.setContentLength(output.length);
        responseHeaders.set("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=file.xml");

        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(output, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

   }
```

The correct way of having the content of file.xml should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <note>
       <to>Tove</to>
       <from>Jani</from>
       <heading>Reminder</heading>
       <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
   </note>
```

Comment: That's not "correct". That's just pretty-printed. Since you're already writing the string by hand, you could just as well pretty-print it by hand. Unless you're doing something more relevant.

Comment: @Kayaman Is there a way of pretty content within the xml file?

Comment: But you don't have an xml file, you have a hard coded String. You're not really even working with XML here, since you don't have any parsers involved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pretty print XML from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java)

Comment: @pringi unfortunately no.

Comment: You can use XSLT for XML file indentation.

Comment: @pringi Finally using the proposed solution with minor modifications it worked.